# How do I manually install a package to Texmaker - Ubuntu 10.10+

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu, texmaker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

At university we have now been given a bunch of `.sty` files which fit the university's template.

I got it to work by just throwing all the files in with the document, however this is messy and I can't help thinking there must be a better way.

So far I've tried putting the files in `/etc/texmf` which I found some references to but I haven't been able to get it to work.

If there is an easier way not using Texmaker - I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the file (i.e. foo.sty) into `/home/user/texmf/tex/latex/foo/foo.sty`

---

UPDATED:
An earlier version of this answer said that you need to run texhash. 
This is wrong. As explained by egreg. This false information came from [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#Installing_packages_manually).

Comment: Don't do `texhash ~/texmf`: it's not necessary. Also, remove any `ls-R` file from `~/texmf`.

Comment: I'm curious: Why not? Is that page wrong? Can you give a link with a rational?

Comment: Yes, that page is wrong. The "personal tree" under `~/texmf` (or `~/Library/texmf` on Mac OS X) is configured so that TeX programs don't need an `ls-R` file for it, but they will use one, if present. The idea is that one can put there files and packages for personal use or for experiments without worrying of doing `texhash` each time the tree is modified. The default setting of `TEXMF` is `TEXMF = {$TEXMFCONFIG,$TEXMFVAR,$TEXMFHOME,!!$TEXMFSYSCONFIG,!!$TEXMFSYSVAR,!!$TEXMFMAIN,!!$TEXMFLOC
AL,!!$TEXMFDIST}`; trees not preceded by `!!` are those that don't require `texhash`.