# How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?

Tags: packages, installing, linux

I need to install a new TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt package on my computer.  I'm running Ubuntu/Fedora/Slackware/Some-Version-Of Linux.  What are the possible ways to do this?

---

***Note:***   We get a number of questions that essentially reduce to this one; it was felt a good idea to have *one* question-and-answer that can cover all the standard methods.  See [Should 'how to install package X on Ubuntu' questions be consolidated?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2670/86) for the discussion.  The question-and-answer are CW so that more information can be easily added.  If you have information to add, please do so.  If you are unsure, leave a comment here or (preferably) in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends).  Comments on the question and answer will be periodically removed to ensure that the information is clear.

Answer (score 169):

### Method 1--(Preferred Method)

**Install the latest TeX Live**

*This is for if the package is in TeX Live and you want to or are using 'vanilla' TeXLive.*

If you haven't yet installed TeX Live, follow the instructions at [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) (these instructions apply to Linux systems in general, not just Debian-based ones).

How you install a package via TeX Live depends on whether you installed TeX Live as a single user or you installed it system-wide.  If the first, try:

```
tlmgr install <package>
```

If the second, you will have a small problem in that `tlmgr` might not be in the path that `sudo` automatically searches.  So you need to locate it first and use `sudo` to call it with the full path.  If your shell has the `which` builtin, you can find `tlmgr` using the command `which tlmgr`.  Thus:

```
which tlmgr
sudo /path/to/tlmgr install <package>
```

If your shell allows you to use the output of a command as a sort of variable, you can use the following command to condense the above (where we exploit the fact that `which` returns a single instance of the command regardless of how many times it appears on the path):

```
sudo $(which tlmgr) install <package>
```

(You can test your shell with the less risky `echo $(which tlmgr)`: this should produce the same as `which tlmgr`.)

### Method 2:

**Find and install the package through your package manager.**

*This is for if you are using the version of TeX that came with your distribution and you don't mind particularly which version of the package you install.*

Linux distributions tend to include TeX as a collection of packages, but it isn't usually on as fine a level as one TeX package equals one Linux package.  You therefore need to find the right distribution package containing the TeX package that you want and install it.  Different package managers have different methods of searching, if all else fails there is often a website where you can search for a specific file:

- Debian

  - [Debian package search](http://packages.debian.org/).
  - If you have Debian installed,
    apt-cache search 
    can help to locate the package.
- Ubuntu

  - [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).
  - apt-cache works like on Debian
- For other distributions, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46700/6245

### Method 3

**Install manually**

In this situation, you have two options: to install system-wide (all users on your system) or to install just for you.  System-wide means that any user on your system will be able to use it, just for you means just that: it will only be installed for your account.  The difference between the two is the base location:

- System-wide: type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` in the Terminal to find the right directory
- Just for you: type `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` in the Terminal to find the right directory

One thing to note here is that in the case of a 'package clash', i.e., the same file is found in multiple places (such as the 'system' location, the 'local' location, and/or the 'individual user' location), only the first instance of the file will be used.  In this case, the order of precedence is *usually*: individual user (`TEXMFHOME`) > local (`TEXMFLOCAL`) > system.  The full list (in the right order) can be determined by running `kpsewhich --var-value TEXINPUTS`.

What happens now depends a bit on the package.  If it is distributed in TDS then you are in luck.  Go to the directory reported by `kpsewhich`, and into the `tex` subdirectory (or create it if it does not exist).  Then extract the TDS file (remember to use `sudo` if globally, and check that your `umask` is set to `022`).  *Note check the TDS file first to ensure that it will extract into the right place: you may need to move up or down a directory to get it to match*.

If it is not distributed in TDS, then there are two options: If the package is available from TeX Live, you can get the TDS packaged version from http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/.tar.xz, and unpack it into a temporary directory. In most cases it will contain subdirectories like tex, fonts, etc. Copy these to the TEXMF tree as decided above. In case it contains a directory texmf-dist or similar, it is a package that also ships some scripts or different things outside the texmf hierarchy, in this case it is the best to contact an expert. Finally, you can also download the package from CTAN or the original distribution channel, unpack it and then there might be instructions - in which case follow them - but the general pattern is pretty similar.  If it is a LaTeX package, create a directory in `<base dir>/tex/latex/<package name>` for it and extract the files (`.sty` plus perhaps `.cls`, *etc.*) there.  Documentation files go in `<base dir>/doc/latex/<package name>`.

If you installed it globally, you will now need to run `mktexlsr` (or equivalently `texhash`) via `sudo`.  If `mktexlsr` is not in the path that `sudo` searches, you will need to locate it.  You can do:

```
which mktexlsr
sudo /path/to/mktexlsr
```

Or if your shell allows it:

```
sudo $(which mktexlsr)
```

This isn't necessary for local installations.

### Method 4:

**Point to it**

*This is for the case where you have a `.sty` or `.cls` file which you don't want to install centrally, for one reason or another.  For example, it may be specific to a particular project (for example an unusual journal style file), or it may be known to clash with other packages, or you may wish to keep it alongside the source files in a repository.*

As described above, the TeX family of programs consult a *path* when looking for input files, including `.sty` and `.cls` files.  You can override this with the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable, which (on unix) consists of a sequence of directories separated by colons; TeX searches each of these directories in turn.  Thus, if you had a `.sty` file in a subdirectory `styles`, then

```
TEXINPUTS=styles:
```

would cause TeX to search for the file in that directory first.

On Windows, you may need to use `;` instead of `:`.

Note the trailing colon: this is followed by an *empty* path element, which causes TeX to insert the standard search path in that position.  Thus `TEXINPUTS=:styles` would cause TeX to search the standard path *before* the subdirectory `styles`.

As above, you can use `kpsewhich` to check things are configured correctly.

```
% ls styles
myfancypackage.sty
% kpsewhich myfancypackage.sty    # doesn't find anything
% export TEXINPUTS=styles:
% kpsewhich myfancypackage.sty
styles/myfancypackage.sty         # found it!
%
```

---

### Notes and Supplementary

#### Note on `sudo`

When you add TeX Live to your path, it will *not* normally be added to the path for the root user, so will not be visible using `sudo`. The methods above use `which` to find `tlmgr` , *etc.*, from the 'normal user' path and pass the correct instruction to `sudo`. This works with the `bash` and `zsh` shells: if you use another shell you may need to provide the full path to `tlmgr` instead.

When running `sudo`, the environment used is a mixture of the superuser's and the local user's.  As well as the path mentioned above, it is important to ensure that the `umask` setting is sufficiently lax: a user should have a `umask` of `077` but root of `022`.  The `umask` controls the default permissions of newly created files: with `077` only root would be able to read (and thus use) them.  With `022`, everyone can read (and possibly execute) them.

If your system does not have `sudo` installed by default, it probably has it in its package repository.  If not, see [How universal is sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48522/6245) for alternatives.

#### Note on `mktexlsr` and `texhash`

To speed up its searching, the `kpathsea` library uses caches in the form of files called `ls-R` in various directories.  These contain all the files that `kpathsea` *would* find if it searched properly in that directory (obeying any recursive search directives).  The files are recreated by the `mktexlsr` command (which is short for "Make TeX's ls-R files") which has to be run manually (by someone with write access to the directory, usually root - see the note on **sudo**) if it is needed.  This command used to be called `texhash` and that is still an alias for this command (technically, a *symlink*).

#### Note on `kpsewhich`

TeX uses the `kpathsea` library for finding its files.  Where this looks depends on various variable which can be set in configuration files or by the user's shell.  The list of directories that `kpathsea` searches in can be displayed by typing `kpsewhich --var-value TEXINPUTS`.  The output is a little condensed.  The following attempts to clarify it a little:

1. Paths are separated by colons (as in environment variables such as `$PATH`)
2. If a path begins with `!!` it means that the `ls-R` file will be consulted instead of the filesystem.
3. If a path ends with `//` it will be searched recursively.
4. Paths or parts of paths can be grouped using braces.

Thus

```
{!!/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist,!!/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var}}//
```

means that `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist` and `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var` will both be searched, in that order.  Both will actually use the cache which is stored in `ls-R` in the base of the search (thus `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/ls-R`, for example).  And both searches will be recursive.

#### Testing the Installation

The simplest way to check that the installed file is being found is to run

```
kpsewhich <package_name>
```

(where `<package_name>` includes the extension).  If this lists the newly installed file, all should be fine.  If it doesn't but does display *something* then it may be that there is another version of this package installed which is being found first.  If that is the case, then

```
kpsewhich --all <package_name>
```

will list all of the matching names so you can test to see if it is finding it at all.

If it did find it but isn't using it, you will either have to choose a location which is searched earlier than the version that is being found or remove the version(s) that are being found first.

If it did not find it at all, there are some possible reasons.

1. If you did a full installation of TeX Live, is the `kpsewhich` command from the new installation?  Try `which kpsewhich` to find out.  If not, adjust your `$PATH` and try again.  (If your path is correct, it might be that your shell hasn't noticed it: try `rehash` to correct this (Bourne-Again Shells)).
2. If you only installed a package, did you put it somewhere that TeX can find it?  The full list of directories in which TeX searches can be found by running

   ```
    kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF
   ```

These are searched recursively.

1. If it is in a directory that TeX searches, and that directory is prepended in the list by `!!` then it is one where TeX consults the cache, not the actual files on the disc.  To recreate the cache, run `mktexlsr` or `texhash` as super-user.

#### Dependent packages

If you do not use the package manager to install TeX or one of its packages (i.e., you didn't use Method 1), then the package manager will not know that what you have just installed is installed. This means that installing system packages that depend on these manually installed packages will try to install them again.  The simplest solution is to let them do so as it is usually the case that your manually installed things are found before the system ones.  If space is tight, many distributions have ["dummy"](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=52642) packages that can be installed to trick the package manager.  See [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for more details.

Comment: AFAICS `sudo tlmgr install foobar` makes foobar installed for root user, but not system-wide (at least on Debian).

Comment: Two remarks for the case of manual per-user installation: **(1)** Often, the source files reside within a git repository. You can then simply `git clone` from within `$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME)/tex/latex`. **(2)** If there is no `.sty` file but an `.ins` file, the `.sty` file can be generated using `latex whatever.ins`.

Answer (score 8):

As I use Ubuntu I have installed TeX Live and of course I use `apt-get` to install packages.

I found that I was missing some files needed to compile my document. Using `apt-cache` as recommended in **Method 1** above I found that `texlive-latex-extra` was the package I needed. However the download size was huge (327 MB).

The essential package only, was easily installed by

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra --no-install-recommends
```

Including the `--no-install-recommends` avoids the huge (320 MB) of extras.

Comment: But how exactly do you use ``apt-get`` to install packages?  Just something like ``apt-get install amssymb``?

Answer (score 4):

If You can't install the package (why ever) You can also put the .sty file next to Your .tex file which uses it. The LaTeX compiler will search in the current directory as well.

Comment: Where is the default location for .sty file for all packages that are installed in TexLive? is it under `/root` or the installation directory of TexLive?

Answer (score 2):

Under OpenSUSE, you can use this command:

```
sudo zypper install 'tex(<package_name>.sty)
```

Note that the OpenSUSE distribution can be installed under Windows 10 easily, through the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Arch Linux, [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#tlmgr) says:

> The `tllocalmgr` utility, provided by [`tllocalmgr-git`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tllocalmgr-git/), lets you
> install (and update) packages from CTAN as pacman packages, see [its
> usage](https://git.archlinux.org/users/remy/texlive-localmanager.git/tree/tllocalmgr#n809) (`-h`) for details.

To install `tllocalmgr-git` one can use an AUR helper such as `yay`:

```
yay -S tllocalmgr-git
```

Then simply run:

```
tllocalmgr
```

and the TexLive Local Manager Shell will be available. To install a package just run:

```
> install threeparttable  # could be anyother package
> texhash                 # refresh the TeX file database
```

Comment: **This information is outdated**. Now it's recommended to use `tlmgr install --usermode ⟨packagename⟩` as explained in the Arch Wiki.

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora 19 (and probably later distributions as well) you can install the (e.g.) multirow.sty package with the following command:

yum install texlive-multirow

You have to log in as root first

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error message about missing files, there is a step even before this: finding which package you need to install.

If you are installing a TeX Live (or MikTeX) package, this will be [a file search on CTAN.org.](https://ctan.org/search?ext=false&FILES=on)  It might return a CTAN package that is not available for installation with your version, but that you still need to install anyway.  In that case, you would follow the “Method 3: Install Manually” instructions from the community-wiki answer.

On Debian or Ubuntu, you can search for the `.deb` package containing a file with `apt-file search`.  The web search will work as well.

If you’re looking for a document class, the file extension will be `.cls`.  A package loaded with `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` will end with `.sty`.  A legacy Type 1 font will consist of multiple files, but you can search for the family name plus `.tfm`.  An old-fashioned METAFONT file will end in `.mf`.

If `fontspec` cannot locate a modern font, it is not always possible to guess what the filename will be.  For example, CMU Typewriter Text Oblique is `cmunst.ttf`.  The document might also be looking for a system font, rather than one in your TeX Live tree specifically, and it might even be one that you have to download from the Web.  On Linux, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX can search your user font directory, `~/.fonts`, or you can put downloaded fonts in a subdirectory of `/usr/local/share/fonts`.  On Windows or (I believe) Mac, there is a trap option! A font must be installed for all users for `fontspec` to find it.  Therefore, if you installed a font only for one user, you might need to reinstall it for all users, or it will display as available but give you a file-not-found error in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

**Debian/Ubuntu specific answer:**

If you know that you want e.g. `outlines.sty`, you could just do

`apt-file search outlines.sty`

and get the result:

`texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/outlines/outlines.sty`

Then you can just proceed with `sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra`.

Note that `apt-file` is usually not installed by default. To have this command, you have to do `sudo apt install apt-file` and then `sudo apt-file update` to fetch the latest info about all available files. Note that this is required so that `apt-file` can find any file that can be provided by *any* package known by your package manager, already installed or otherwise. If you think package repositories have changed so much that the existing info about provided files is no longer up to date, you can just run `sudo apt-file update` again.