# Create CV with moderncv in relative folder

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to create my CV in LaTeX but got into problems. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, the package `texlive-latex-extra` includes the 2008 version of moderncv, but I want to use the newer 2012 moderncv version which has it's differences. I cannot uninstall that package because some packages there are used by other documents.

I've downloaded the new moderncv from CTAN but I'm having trouble using it. I'm trying to organize my document using the following layout:

- `style/` <- moderncv files, *.sty, *.cls, etc.
- `publish/` <- pdflatex output.
- `cv.tex` <- My CV.
- `publications.bib` <- My publications.
- `face.png` <- Photo.
- `Makefile` <- Makefile :P

In my Makefile I have:

```
all:
    TEXINPUTS=./style//:$TEXINPUTS pdflatex -halt-on-error -output-directory ./publish/ ./cv.tex
clean:
    rm -rf ./publish/*
```

The problem comes here:

When I try to `make` I got several errors:

```
(./style/moderncv.cls
Document Class: moderncv 2012/08/10 v1.1.3 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class
! LaTeX Error: File `size11.clo' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `etoolbox.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `ifthen.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `xcolor.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `fontenc.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `T1' for package `fontenc'.
```

An I don't know how to fix them.

I can compile the document if I move the `style/*` files (moderncv classes) to the same directory as the `cv.tex` file but that's a mess. What am I missing?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  ubuntu comes with a really old distribution. You should update to current release.

Comment: There is a [generic question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/8528) that deals with this problem from Debian/Ubuntu.  I do not recommend that you mess about with `TEXINPUTS` for something this simple.

Comment: You need to following the instructions listed under [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764), rather than installing packages manually. For TeX Live, this should be as simple as a command line `tlmgr update --self --all`.

Comment: Also it looks to me as if you are trying to tell `pdflatex` that everything it needs to find will be in the `style` directory, which clearly isn't true.  You should either update your TeX distribution, or update only the relevant packages (say, if bandwidth is a problem).  The answer linked to in my earlier comment shows you how to do either method.  The even more short-term, and not recommended solution is, as you've figured out, to leave the `moderncv` stuff in the working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was just an error in the Makefile. Instead of using `$TEXINPUTS` I should have used `$(TEXINPUTS)`. This is the corrected Makefile:

```
all:
    TEXINPUTS=./style//:$(TEXINPUTS) pdflatex -halt-on-error -output-directory ./publish/ ./cv.tex
clean:
    rm -rf ./publish/*
```

And this is my current Makefile:

```
PUBLISH=./publish/
PKGS=TEXINPUTS=./style//:$(TEXINPUTS)

LATEX=/usr/bin/pdflatex
LATEXOPT=-halt-on-error -interaction errorstopmode -output-directory $(PUBLISH) ./cv.tex

BIBTEX=/usr/bin/bibtex
BIBTEXOPT=$(PUBLISH)cv

all: clean compile bibliography recompile open

clean:
    rm -rf $(PUBLISH)*

compile:
    $(PKGS) $(LATEX) $(LATEXOPT)

bibliography:
    $(BIBTEX) $(BIBTEXOPT)

recompile:
    $(PKGS) $(LATEX) $(LATEXOPT)
    $(PKGS) $(LATEX) $(LATEXOPT)

open:
    xdg-open $(PUBLISH)cv.pdf
```

And is working perfectly :)

Comment: Glad you sorted it out! Just as FYI, you can also create a "local" (for every user of your system) and/or "home" (for yourself only) texmf tree. That way, you can add/modify any packages without interfering with your base LaTeX installation. LaTeX is smart enough to handle different trees and give your home/local tree higher priority over the global one.