# tlmgr usage to get a package from CTAN

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

I'd like to install this package:

http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cookybooky

Is it possible to do this using tlmgr?

I tried something like this, but it looks like I don't know what I am doing:

```
$ sudo tlmgr repository http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ install cookybooky
tlmgr: unknown directive to tlmgr repository: http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/
```

I am doing this on a macbook (TeX Live 2012).

Comment: See [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-370003.4.6) for instructions on how to install packages into your TeXLive installation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot install it with the TeXLive manager, because it is no more part of any repository. Install it "by hand" from CTAN.

Save the two files `cookybooky.dtx` and `cookybooky.ins` in a temporary directory and then run `latex  cookybooky.ins` which creates the documentation and, of course, the style file cookybooky.sty

Comment: The doc is obtained with `pdflatex cookybooky.dtx`

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to run any other commands to update the local tex installation?

Comment: @M-V -- after creating the .sty (and, possibly, the .pdf) file, you should run `texhash` or `mktexlsr` to update the database for TeX's lookup of file names.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, but I had to copy the files to ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/ before I stopped getting errors about missing cookybooky.sty. Even now, I am getting an error about a missing web.sty - I guess I am missing some packages.

Comment: you can test if a package is installed or found by TeX with running from the terminal `kpsewhich web.sty` or any other package

Comment: The [documentation](ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cookybooky/documentation/Manual.pdf#page=4) has a section about requirements. `web.sty` is part of [AcroTeX eDucation Bundle](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq.html) that is not in TeX Live either.