# Manually install packages from dtx file on ubuntu

Tags: packages, installing, ubuntu, standalone, dtx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

My TeXLive doesn't have the `standalone` package. I read part of the documentation, the PDF file from the [standalone package in the CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone). In case of `tlmgr` it suggests a manual installation if one uses Ubuntu, as is my case.

What usually works for me is copying the `.sty` or `.cls` files into the right path and then `texhash`. In the case of `standalone` the `.zip` bundle doesn't include those kind of files but `.dtx` and `.ins` files.

Could somebody spell out how to manually install those kind of files?

Comment: Simply run `latex standalone.ins` and this will produce the `.sty`, `.cls` `.cfg` files and a `.tex` file; if you run latex `standalone.dtx` you will also have the documentation.

Comment: You should consider installing TeX Live 2012, which is available through a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa) and should be included in the next release of Ubuntu.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The `ydoc.cls` is required only to produce the documentation, which you can find online at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf

Comment: @JorgeCampos then this file (used internally by standalone to generate the package documentation) is missing in your system; you will need to also install `ydoc.cls`. As you see, resolving dependences might take you some time; beter install TeX Live2012; see egreg's comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to unpack the files manually or create the documentation:
[CTAN:install/macros/latex/standalone.tds.zip](http://mirror.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/standalone.tds.zip)
already contains all files for the installation. You only need it to unpack it into your
TEXMFHOME or TEXMFLOCAL tree. For example, installing in the home texmf tree:

```
$ unzip standalone.tds.zip -d ~/texmf
```

After installing in the local texmf tree, you need to call

```
$ sudo texhash
```