# I'm unable to install unicode-math package ubuntu 16.04

Tags: packages

I've been struggled trying to install the `unicode-math` package manually since I don't know if there is another way to accomplish it.

So I downloaded the entire package from CTAN.

And I followed the instructions given in this post.

[Manually install packages from dtx file on ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77564/manually-install-packages-from-dtx-file-on-ubuntu)

But after doing it and compiling a TeX archive with XeLaTeX, It stills giving the same error and LaTeX indicates that the .sty file is not installed.

So any help is appreciated.

PS. I'm using TexMaker as my TeX editor.

Greetings.

Comment: If you don't have unicode-math in your tex system it is quite probable that you also don't have a current expl3, fontspec and a current latex.  Can't you install a vanilla texlive?

Comment: I've installed vanilla texlive but I can't install that package yet because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Adrian `unicode-math` is a standard package so is in a 'vanilla' TeX Live install: can you say exactly what you did?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 installs TeXlive 2015. Anything later requires manual install from TUG. Might that be the problem?

Comment: For TeX Live installed via `apt` (i.e., not vanilla), there is the `texlive-math-extra` package which includes `unicode-math` (and all dependencies), which can be installed with `sudo apt install texlive-math-extra` (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/texlive-math-extra).