# How to install the documentclass standalone in Ubuntu?

Tags: document-classes, ubuntu, standalone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

Is there an easy way to install the documentclass `standalone` in Ubuntu using `apt-get`?

In other words, is there a `texlive` package for Ubuntu that contains `standalone`? Does this package belong to the standard package repository? Otherwise, how do I obtain it.

I would like to live this life without ever learning how to use any LaTeX package manager.

Comment: The texlive distribution found in the ubuntu repos is somewhat outdated. You should install tl with the script found here http://www.tug.org/texlive/ . Any further updates should be made with `tlmgr` tool shiped with tl. If you don't want to use this, ask canonical for better support.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's exactly what I would like to avoid. I do not want to install anything in Ubuntu except through the Ubuntu package repository, and I do not want to learn how to use `tlmgr`. Is there a minimal solution such as downloading `standalone` and copying it to some `texmf` folders? (Really, one should not have to worry about these things.)

Comment: Not using `apt-get`. You certainly could add standalone to your local texmf-local directory, but in case that this packages depends on other packages with a certain version number you need to update all these packages by yourself. BTW neither texlive itself nor tlmgr are hard to handle. And as long  canonical  keeps with their repos standards this will be the golden way.

Comment: [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) covers the general case: there is nothing special about `standalone` in this regard.

Comment: You can also download a TDS ZIP file of `standalone` under https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/downloads. Simply unzip this under your local TEXMF tree (e.g. `~/texmf` under Linux) and update the package database (e.g. `texhash ~/texmf`).

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment

> Is there a minimal solution such as downloading `standalone` and copying it to some `texmf` folders?

Yes, you can do this manually. Here are some basic instructions for a manual install of `standalone` (or any package, whether available from CTAN or not).

1. Download `standalone` from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone)
2. Create a new directory called `standalone` (or really whatever you'd like) in your `texmf`.
3. Place all downloaded files in your directory you just created.
4. If a `.ins` file is provided, run `latex standalone.ins` (or something similar)
5. Run `texhash` from the command line. This will inform `latex` that new packages have been placed for install.

That should get you rolling. I'm running this from memory (honestly, just learning to use the package managers (like `tlmgr`) makes life *so* much easier), so forgive me if I made a mistake.

Of course, you can always follow the sure-to-be-correct instructions over at [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Installing_Extra_Packages). It also has instructions for creating the documentation yourself, which I've skipped over here.

---

Just remember TeXLive's own [documentation](http://tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html):

> First, you may have gotten a TeX installation that was based on TeX Live but was packaged for your operating system. For instance, the free GNU/Linux distributions, and the distributions from Red Hat, Debian, Ubuntu, SUSE, etc., all make TeX installations derived from TeX Live available through their normal packaging system (`rpm`, `apt-get`, `yum`, etc.). If this is how you got your TeX, the timing and content of updates is entirely up to your operating system provider—contact them with any and all questions.

Good luck!