# Two column text question and choices

Tags: macros, columns

i am trying to create a command for a matching type of question. left column are the questions and on the right column are the choices. My problem is how will I do this, especially on the right column. How can I make a column of choices corresponding with the length of the total questions?

example output is:

[image]

follow up question. If inspite of writing `a. choice1`, is changing letter a to a small box possible?

better if could use the command like this:

```
  \documentclass{exam}
  \usepackage{longtable,tabu}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{mytabu}\boxedcolchoice
  \question{text text text text text}{choice1}\\
  \question{text text text text text here text here}{choice2}\\
  \end{mytabu}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: You mean both columns should have same height regardless of item number or every item should be leveled with its opposite?

Comment: yes! precisely that's what I needed.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to present two options. can you repeat once again for the sake of completeness which one did you confirmed?

Comment: I mean every item should be leveled with its opposite. :)

Comment: In that case, you can simply use a table, no?

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possible solution using the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) and [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) packages. The command `\myquestion` is in charge of typesetting the entries; it has two mandatory arguments: the first one contains the text for the question, and the second one, for the corresponding text for the choice. The row numbering and the boxes are automatically included:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\mybox{%
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{\fbox{\rule{0.5em}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{0.5em}}}}
\newcommand\myquestion[2]{& #1 & & #2}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=3pt
\begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{
  >{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
  X[3]
  @{\hspace*{2em}}
  >{\mybox}l
  @{\hspace*{4pt}}X
}
\myquestion{Here's the text for the first question; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice1}  \\
\myquestion{Here's the text for the second question; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice2}  \\
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A new requirement has been made in a comment; to be able to have the `longtabu` width and format specification as parameters; this can be done defining a new `mytabu` environment with two mandatory arguments (the first one could be also defined as optional with a default value): the first argument is the width of the `longtabu`, and the second one, gives the format specification. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\mybox{%
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{\fbox{\rule{0.5em}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{0.5em}}}}
\newcommand\myquestion[2]{& #1 & & #2}
\newenvironment{mytabu}[2]
  {\tabulinesep=3pt
    \begin{longtabu} to #1{#2}
  }
  {\end{longtabu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabu}{\textwidth}{
  >{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
  X[3]
  @{\hspace*{2em}}
  >{\mybox}l
  @{\hspace*{4pt}}X
}
\myquestion{Here's the text for the first question; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice1}  \\
\myquestion{Here's the text for the second question; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice2}  \\
\end{mytabu}

\end{document}
```

Now a new requirement made in an edit to the original question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{myrow}
\newcommand\mybox{%
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{\fbox{\rule{0.5em}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{0.5em}}}}
\newcommand\myquestion[2]{& #1 & & #2}
\newenvironment{mytabu}
  {\tabulinesep=3pt
    \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth{>{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
  X[3]
  @{\hspace*{2em}}
  >{\mybox}l
  @{\hspace*{4pt}}X}
  }
  {\end{longtabu}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabu}
\myquestion{Here's the text for the first question; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice1}  \\
\myquestion{Here's the text for the second question; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line; and we add some text to apan more than one line.}{choice2}  \\
\end{mytabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried to install the tabu.sty for it is not found. But, it prompt no tlmgr found. I made to install this two but i failed for it says ubuntu version i think cant support it? i guess. So is there other way to solve my problem?

Comment: i encountered this kind of problem in my ubuntu and it says no way to fix it.

Comment: @kayla Perhaps this post can help you with your installation problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system. My crystal ball says you are using `Ubuntu 12.04` and you are still probably using `TeXLive 2009`. Install TeXLive 2012 instead. If you want to install the package manually, then you can follow the directions in the link. But creating a folder `texmf` in your `home` directory and unziping the package to `~/texmf/tex/latex` usually works.

Comment: previously i tried to place my `mdframed` package in the home directly. I copy it so I can paste it. But what happened when is i can't paste the folder in ~/texmf/tex/latex. In short, the system doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: @gonzalo .. this code :`\textwidth{
  >{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
  X[3]
  @{\hspace*{2em}}
  >{\mybox}l
  @{\hspace*{4pt}}X
}` after the `\begin{longtabu}` is this possible to define as a variable also? i will be putting the code probably in my class if it can possibly make as variable.

Comment: @kayla of course you can do that. What do you want to be variable, the lengths used or the whole format specification?.

Comment: It be better if its the whole format specification so that it can be more appropriate and consistent.

Comment: @kayla please see my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Is there possible way to eliminate this `{\textwidth}{
  >{\stepcounter{myrow}\themyrow.}l
  X[3]
  @{\hspace*{2em}}
  >{\mybox}l
  @{\hspace*{4pt}}X
}` in the `\begin{mytabu}`?

Comment: please see my updated question which i am hoping to have created

Comment: @kayla please see my updated answer; the third code does what you want.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I included the commands into myownclass. So what I am using now is `\documentclass{myownclass}` instead of `documentclass{article}` But it always provides me an error that `\begin{longtabu}` is undefined though I already require the Packages longtable annd tabu. Is there solution for this? I have updated my question for you to see what I think would make the file function using myownclass.

Comment: @kayla without seeing the code you are using in your class is hard to tell; anyways, this seems to be a new problem so I think it's better for you to open a new question for it (after all, the original problem has now been solved) providing all necessary background information and (if you consider so) mark this answer as accepted.