# Create a two column matching type question?

Tags: macros, two-column, width

I am currently looking for some ways to create a command that would give two column. I have a similar problem to this link : [Two column text and choices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85321/two-column-text-question-and-choices#comment183608_85321)

Two column questions and choices is also my problem. Hope I could get a help for creating a macro for this. I prefer this each question corresponds with its opposite equally in the same level.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question you linked to. Is it something like that what you need?