# uniform indent on description

Tags: lists, indentation, description

I have a description like below.  The main issue is if the text is to long it runs underneath the beginning.

```
\begin{description}
    \item[Languages:] C, C++,Python, Ruby, Shell Scripting (Bash), JavaScript, PHP, Ruby On Rails. Java, C\#, X86, MIPS, Lisp, Standard ML, Scheme, XML, HTML
    \item[OS:] Windows, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, AIX, UNIX
\end{description}
```

What happens is the end of the languages item goes under "Languages".  It starts about right in the middle.  I want it to go and start right under C.
I desire it to look like so

```
Languages: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
           AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
           AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

not

```
Languages: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{url,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]    {  \marginpar{\textsf{{\footnotesize\vspace{-1em}\flushright #1}}}}

\def\ind{\hangindent=1 true cm\hangafter=1 \noindent}

\def\labelitemi{~}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{~}

\reversemarginpar

\marginhead{{\vskip 0.3em}Entertainment}
\medskip

\begin{description}[align=right,labelindent=!]
\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5\baselineskip}
\item[Sports:] Football, Baseball, Soccer, Rugby, Tennis, Basketball, badminton, swimming, track and field, diving, 
\item[Television Shows:] The Sopranos, The price is right, Dr. Phil, Dexter, CSI, CSI New York, CSI Miami, Las Vegas, Breaking Bad, LA Law, Law and Order.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the package eqlist to be very helpful for such instances. The code given by hpesoj626 can be rewritten as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{eqlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqlist}
    \item[Languages:] C, C++,Python, Ruby, Shell Scripting (Bash), JavaScript, PHP, Ruby On Rails. Java, C\#, X86, MIPS, Lisp, Standard ML, Scheme, XML, HTML
    \item[OS:] Windows, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, AIX, UNIX
    \item[lipsum:] \lipsum[1]
\end{eqlist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) When compiling the (completely different MWE) provided by OP, use `\longitem` for Telivision shows.

Comment: This version worked well.

Answer (score 7):

Will this do for you?

### Code

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91122/uniform-indent-on-description
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[align=right,labelindent=!]
    \item[Languages:] C, C++,Python, Ruby, Shell Scripting (Bash), JavaScript, PHP, Ruby On Rails. Java, C\#, X86, MIPS, Lisp, Standard ML, Scheme, XML, HTML
    \item[OS:] Windows, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, AIX, UNIX
    \item[lipsum:] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### For the MWE provided: 2013/01/12

I don't know what you are using the difinition of `\labelitemi` and `\labelitemii` so I removed them from the solution below. With `enumitem` you can use the option `leftmargin=<length>` to manually set up the horizontal distance from the left margin. You can replace `1.75\marginparwidth` with a length you prefer, say `1.5in`. I just included the `showframe` option to `geometry` package so that you can see the borders for the margins.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{url,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\marginhead}[1]{\marginpar{\textsf{{\footnotesize\vspace{-1em}\flushright #1}}}}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\marginhead{{\vskip 0.3em}Entertainment}
\medskip

\begin{description}[align=right,labelindent=!,leftmargin=1.75\marginparwidth]
%\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5\baselineskip}
\item[Sports:] Football, Baseball, Soccer, Rugby, Tennis, Basketball, badminton, swimming, track and field, diving, 
\item[Television Shows:] The Sopranos, The price is right, Dr. Phil, Dexter, CSI, CSI New York, CSI Miami, Las Vegas, Breaking Bad, LA Law, Law and Order.
\item[Languages:] C, C++,Python, Ruby, Shell Scripting (Bash), JavaScript, PHP, Ruby On Rails. Java, C\#, X86, MIPS, Lisp, Standard ML, Scheme, XML, HTML
\item[OS:] Windows, Ubuntu, Mint, Fedora, AIX, UNIX
\item[lipsum:] \lipsum[1]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  It first complains like so


! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.199 ...n{description}[align=right,labelindent=!]

If I add a number in where ! is it just shifts over the entire item lines

Comment: @Bobdul Can you put `\listfiles` in your preamble and look at your `.log` file to see the versions of packages you are running? I run this with `enumitem 2011/09/28 v.3.5.2`. What operating system are you using anyway?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  Seems I have an older version

enumitem.sty    2009/05/18 v2.2 Customized lists

Comment: I suggest you install TeXLive 2012. See this post on how to install Vanilla TeXLive 2012: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu. There is also a post in askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012. As for installing individual packages. See also this post if you want to install individual packages from CTAN: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system

Comment: I installed the newest Texlive.  one issue I have though is the overall items are being moved over to the left onto the margin.  They aren't staying put.  Even if I cut the longer lines with \\ the item is still moving over.  If I don't use [align=right,labelindent=!] it goes away.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Bobdul I can't see what is happening in your code unless you provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), one which begins with `\documentclass` complete with `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. Can you strip your document down to the least amount of code which compiles and which produces the weird outcome and then come back here for the update?

Comment: added in the OP