# Installing packages for linux on texworks

Tags: installing

I am fairly new to ubuntu and I just installed TexWorks. Everything works fine but can someone give me step by step to install packages. With Windows I used the MikTex package manager but I am lost on how to install packages for linux.

Please let me know the best and easiet solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`Texworks` is a TeX editor, not a TeX distribution (as far as I know). The way to manage packages will depend on which TeX distribution you are using / how you installed TeX. The most common are installing TeX Live either through Ubuntu's package manager (`apt-get` or a GUI version of it) or manually (`tlmgr`).

### apt-get

If you installed TeX through Ubuntu's package manager, everything will be handled through it too. Look for packages called `texlive-...`, i.e., to install `pstricks`, use the command

```
apt-get install texlive-pstricks
```

This way of installing teX on Ubuntu is common as it easy, but the drawback is that packages can be (significantly) outdated, as updates are infrequent.

### tlmgr

Installing TeXLive directly (called a "vanilla" installation) is a little more hassle, but you get the benefits of an up-to-date installation.
There is already a howto on TeX.sx on how to perform such an installation: [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
As for how to manage packages, you will then be using a tool called `tlmgr`. The full documentation is [available online](http://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html), and the short answer is that you install packages with

```
tlmgr install <package name>
```

and update the whole system with

```
tlmgr update -all
```

Comment: Is there a way I can install the tlmgr utility without uninstalling and then reinstalling using the vanilla method.

Comment: @masfenix -- No.  The Debian/Ubuntu repositories package their own version of TeX Live and it does not (and will not) include `tlmgr`.  Installing packages yourself is not hard (especially those packages as `.tds.zip` --- lots are, but not all), but requires you to be somewhat confident when it comes to the command line.  You can install the Ubuntu TeX Live in parallel with the 'real' TeX Live if you have the disk space.  You should read [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/8528).

Comment: I've installed texlive directly - vanilla installation. However I don't know where my editor is?! calling `texworks` from terminal dosnt do anything

Comment: TeXworks is only distributed directly with TeX Live on Windows (and with MacTeX on OS X). On Ubuntu, you can install it easily with `apt-get install texworks`. Note that Gedit is quite a good editor in my opinion too (with some plugins, `gedit-plugins-latex` I believe). TeXmaker and Kile are other options.

Answer (score 0):

When after a vanilla installation of texlive I say `sudo apt-get -s install texworks` to simulate the installation, it seems as if it wants to install a lot of tex all over again, not knowing about texlive being installed already. -- Thomas

Comment: Please do not highjack a question please repost a question of your own. That being said, you need to tell your system that you have installed something equivalent to Ubuntu TeX Live. The method is described here: http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html, see the section "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian"