# Is there a Latex IDE for ubuntu that "just works"?

Tags: packages, installing

The most frustrating experience with latex on linux is the management of packages. I want to use Latex but I don't have the time/energy to manually install every package or figure out how to get `tlmgr` to work.

On Windows `texworks` installs packages automatically, but on `ubuntu` [it doesn't](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95610/installing-packages-for-linux-on-texworks).

Is there an IDE for ubuntu that will install packages automatically without me having to go through more than the most rudimentary of installation procedures?

Comment: are you sure it is texworks doing the auto-install (rather than miktex) but unless you are very short of space why not just do a full install originally that is simpler than trying to install everything on demand as is the usual way with texlive, even on windows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was hoping to avoid a full install but I guess it's the best solution I've come across so far. Thanks.

Comment: There is no “auto install” feature on Unix systems, unlike the one in MiKTeX. Just install the whole TeX Live and live happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there´s no IDE with automatic package installation under Linux. If you want, install texlive-full once and you´ll have no problems in the future. In ubuntu that would be done as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

This will install all the packages and will use quite a bit of disk space.

Comment: alternatively: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu