# Harvard Reference using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

I'm trying to build a Harvard reference template using biblatex.  I at first gave the [Harvard package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) a try but was then informed that this package is out-dated and instead should use biblatex.  After setting up LaTex ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/a-complete-biblatex-example-from-start-to-end)) I went through the lovely 91 examples that came with the biblatex package.  Sadly *none* of them had any full Harvard example.  Which is a little strange seeing as this is the almost de-facto when it comes to references for academic papers.

My current code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
}
@ONLINE
{CUEDCplusplus,
     AUTHOR  = "Love, T.P.",
     TITLE   = "{CUED C++}",
     URL = "http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++.html",
     URLYEAR = 2010,
     PRESORT="aa"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}

In 1988 C was totally awesome. \cite{KandR}
According to \cite{CUEDCplusplus} C++ was even better.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Does anybody know how I can instead have an output that fully matches the Harvard referencing system.

In other words, instead of looking like this (as it currently does)
[image: Current output]

It will look like this (The bibliography is correct though, so no need to change that)
[image: Want]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The 'Harvard' system is not really a reference style, it's a very broad term used for author-date styles.

Comment: The command `\cite{<key>}` can't read your mind as to when you want parenthetical citations versus citations as nouns. In the biblatex examples for the author-year styles you should have come across `\parencite` and `\textcite`. Loading biblatex with `natbib=true` will allow you to use natbib-like citation commands.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are almost as many flavours of author-year bibliography and citation style as there are of Christianity.

Depending on what you need, you should just be able to use `\autocite`, `\parencite`, or `\textcite` rather than `\cite`. Just to give a flavour:

```
In 1988 C was totally awesome \parencite{KandR},
while according to \textcite{CUEDCplusplus} C++ was even better.
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The `harvard` citation management *package* does two things rather nicely. First, it provides several authoryear-style citation commands, including `\citeasnoun` and `\possessivecite`, that aren't provided by the core LaTeX system. Second, the `harvard` package provides several predefined bibliography styles. These are, in alphabetical order: `agsm`, `aspr`, `dcu`, `jmr`, `jphysics8`, `kluwer`, and `nederlands`. Which one of these styles were you planning on using?

I wasn't aware that the `harvard` package was "out-dated", as you put it. However, it is true that whereas the `hyperref` package works extremely well with the `natbib` citation management package, it works slightly less well with the `harvard` package. If you're a fan of the `\citeasnoun` and `\possessivecite` commands and don't wish to stop using them just because you want full interoperability with `hyperref`, here's a solution: Load both the `natbib` and the `har2nat` packages. (You have three guesses as to what the `har2nat` package does...) That way, you can use all of the `harvard` package's citation commands and fully use any and all of the package's bibliography styles, while enjoying full interoperability with `hyperref`.

Comment: I heard that the Harvard package was outdated http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/

But if you can still use it, what are the advantages? ie: Are the Harvards Package's \citeasnoun and \possessivecite  better than biblatex's \parencite or \textcite?

Comment: @JohnCrawford - The `\parencite` and `\textcite` commands of the `\biblatex` package are very similar to the `\citep` and `\citet` commands of the `natbib` package. The macro `\citeasnoun` of the `\harvard` package is replicated by `natbib`'s `\citeauthor` command. To replicate `harvard`'s `\possessivecite` command, you could load the `har2nat` package. Do read the user guide to familiarize yourself with the `harvard` package's citation-related commands and various bibliography styles. By the way, the link you provide doesn't seem to support the claim that the package is outdated.