# Putting Serial Numbers in References

Tags: biblatex

I wish to have a citation in the text as follows:

> However with growing sustainability concerns (Madu, 2001),
>   organizations need to undertake suitable measures to improve their
>   sustainability aspects (Amrina & Yusof, 2011).

And in respective references, I need a list of references along with the serial numbers in such a manner that in text full citation is restored as such.

> 1. Amrina, E., & Yusof, S. M. (2011). Key performance indicators for sustainable manufacturing evaluation in automotive companies. 2011
>      IEEE International Conference on Industrial Engineering and
>      Engineering Management, (pp. 1093 - 1097).
> 2. Madu, C. (2001). Handbook of environmentally conscious manufacturing. Kluwer Academic Publishers.

I have been using following code:

```
\bibliographystyle{apa-good} % for last name as references
\bibliography{total}
```

Please help.

Comment: I'm thinking I'm not the only one... I am sorry but I really don't understand your question: Are you happy with the way the citation appears in the text but you want to have a number at the beginning of each reference in the bibliography and `apa-good` is not providing the style that you like?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @FionaSmith - Yes, exactly just like in word we can put serial numbers to the list of references, the same way i am not able to achieve the same in latex. however the citation in text is required as such only with complete details. Can you please guide for some way out.

Comment: Still not sure I've got it! Do you want the citation in the text to read **However with growing sustainability concerns (Madu, C., 2001. Handbook of environmentally conscious manufacturing. Kluwer Academic Publishers.)** or are you happy with **However with growing sustainability concerns (Madu, 2001)**? I doubt I can help you personally but it would help others to help you if what you want is clearly stated. Perhaps you could modify your question to make it clear exactly what you want!

Comment: @FionaSmith - I require (Madu, 2001) as it is in my text but with the code mentioned in above question i am only getting my list of references with out serial numbers. So i need to add serial numbers  in front of all the references now in addition to it.

Comment: The "serial numbers" that are in some lists of references are the citation keys. When a reference looks like "[2]" or "²" that number is what you look up in the list.

When you have author-year citations there are no numbers correponding to the entries. It's hard to see why you would want numbers there.

Comment: @pst - i had explained the same to my guide but simply because he requires serial numbering done to the references in addition to the normal style, i am thereby trying to look for it too.

Comment: I expect you can make some modifications somewhere to get it to write out a number if that's what you really want. Have you hunted around for a different bibliography style file? I can't help because I don't know how to do it, but I did manage to make a minor modification to the style file that I use, so you might be able to combine parts of two style files to get the behvaiour you want?

Comment: @FionaSmith - Well yes that sounds very good. Thanks, i will try to do it. However i am also not that expert in coding but can try once. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) supports independent citation and bibliography styles. Working from [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/), [Harvard Reference using Biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102662/), and [How to add a comma between author and year](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134063/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

In 1988 C was totally awesome. \autocite{KandR}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Mhhh, if you are using `bibstyle=numeric`, there seems to be no reason to redefine `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}`. (Save for changing the number format, but that can be done more elegantly via `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1.}`). You could of course stick to the new definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` and just go with `style=authoryear` (so you do not even need different `citestyle`/`bibstyle`s).

Comment: Edited to go with redefining `labelnumberwidth`. Much simpler for this case. Thanks.