# Citation style and arranging references

Tags: biblatex

Following is the latex code provided by @Mike Renfro from [Putting Serial Numbers in References](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171593/putting-serial-numbers-in-references)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}

\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

In 1988 C was totally awesome. \autocite{KandR}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

However in the text at same time if I have to use (Kernighan and Ritchie, 1988) and at some places Kernighan and Ritchie (1988) then what will be the citing style for second scenario.

Moreover in references, i also need them to appear like this:

1. Kernighan, B.W. and Ritchie, D.M. The C Programming Lan- guage Second Edition. Prentice-Hall, Inc., 1988.

ie last name appearing first and accordingly all refernces are arranged in alphabetically order according to last name of first author.

How it can be done. Please help.

Comment: Ad 1: `\textcite{KandR}`? Ad 2: `sorting=nty`/`sorting=nyt` (name-title-year/name-year-title) and `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}`

Comment: @moewe - Where is "sorting=nty/sorting=nyt (name-title-year/name-year-title) and \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}" to be added in the above code ?

Comment: Add `sorting` to the load-time options, so `\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` reads `\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex,sorting=nty]{biblatex}` or `\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}` afterward. `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}` should be added somewhere in the preamble after `biblatex` was loaded (put it before `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}`, for example).

Comment: @moewe - \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} is not making references to start from last name. Kindly look into it.

Comment: Try `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` instead.

Comment: @moewe Would you make an answer out of your comments?

Comment: @Christoph Done!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `sorting` option at loading time (you probably want `nty`: "name-title-year" and `nyt`: "name-year-title", for more sorting options look at pp. 44 sq. of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the sectioned linked from there).

The call to `biblatex` would then read (with "name-year-title" sorting)

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt]{b‌​iblatex}
```

To change the name format, go with

```
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
```

Full MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex,sorting=nyt]{b‌​iblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

In 1988 C was totally awesome. \autocite{KandR}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```