# biblatex2 style file not found

Tags: biblatex

After following the instructions here :[A complete Biblatex example - from start to end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/a-complete-biblatex-example-from-start-to-end/102311#102311) and using the sample `test1.tex` file, I am unable to figure out why I keep getting the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex2.sty' not found.
```

I am eventually attempting to implement OSCOLA via TexMaker but I can't even get a basic file using Biblatex working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your *preamble* to the question?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you sure the numeral `2` in `biblatex2` is needed?

Comment: Why don't you start with the examples provided with the `biblatex` package itself? have a look at your `/texmf/doc/latex/biblatex/examples` folder. It is plenty of samples.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You need the whole `biblatex` distribution, not just the `biblatex.sty` file.  It loads amongst other things `biblatex2.sty`

Comment: @ Pouya. Preamble as stated in the link: \documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@BOOK
    {KandR,
     AUTHOR  = "Kernighan, Brian W. and Ritchie, Dennis M.",
     TITLE   = "{The C Programming Language Second Edition}",
     PUBLISHER = "Prentice-Hall, Inc.",
     YEAR = 1988
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{refs.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Hello\cite{KandR}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}

Comment: @Mico biblatx2.sty is obviously coming from the running of the original tex file. Besides, I just dropped a copy of that sty file into the working directory as a workaround. That was ok, but I think it reflects something more serious as the test1.tex did not compile.

Comment: @ Andrew, I have the whole biblatex distribution, the error shows up anyway. my workaround was to drop the style file into the working directory, but this is simply masking a deeper problem

Comment: Well, I managed to get the outputted result I wanted, but it is not to my satisfaction. Basically it involved installing ubuntu 13.10 which has a more recent texlive which includes a later version of biber and biblatex. i am still unable to configure texmaker correctly with biber but my tex file using oscola is compiling via the command line. I don't recommend this `solution' but I'll endeavor to use it until I can get a satisfactory result. Of interest is that the oscola standard is packaged correctly in 13.10 (alpha daily build).

Comment: Update. I now have texmaker working correctly and compiling a large and complicated document using oscola. There are some non-fatal error messages which I'll fix later. Of course now I have a bigger porblem-how to implement this solution on a stable release of Ubuntu. I'll try to do it on 12.04 LTS as I think that will appeal to most interested users.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an installation problem already solved by the OP.