# Errors when build with bib file

Tags: biblatex

I tried to follow this link to use Biblatex
[[A complete Biblatex example - from start to end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102134/a-complete-biblatex-example-from-start-to-end#][1])
However, when i tried to build it as pdflatex biblatex, pdflatex*2, i didnt get anything with errors shown as
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: biblograph.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file biblograph.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file biblograph.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file biblograph.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

After some research online without any success, anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: With `biblatex` you want to be running either `pdflatex biber pdflatex pdflatex` or if you pass `backend=biber` to `biblatex` then you need to run `pdflatex bibtex pdflatex pdflatex`.  Can you provide a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407) which should be but isn't compiling successfully at your end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am not sure about biber, i am using Texmaker, the only option i find there is Bibtex

Comment: See [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162) for how to set the editor up to compile with `biber` or alternatively use `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`.  If not you'll have to provide a minimal working example to show us what it is you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

By default TeXmaker is configured to use `bibtex`. To use `biber`, go to `Options > Configure TeXmaker`  and  change the line for `Bib(la)tex` as in this screenshot (this one is for MiKTeX on its own partition – adapt the path to your needs):

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, it might be a dumb question, but i can find the biber executed file anywhere, do i need to download it?

Comment: No, it's part of the distribution. The important point is the syntax for parameters. I guess they're same on every platform.

Comment: then where i can find the biber file, by the way i am using ubuntu.

Comment: Under windows, it is the same `bin`  directory as the other executable files. So where you find `bibtex`, you should find `biber`. Why don't use `TeX Live Manager` (`tlmgr`) to check whether its is installed , and ask to install it if it's not?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i am pretty sure that i dont have biber installed.

Comment: I think you should update to TeX Live 2016, there were some important changes this year.