# etoolbox.sty missing

Tags: debian

im using Debian squeeze and installed LaTeX with `apt-get install texlive texlive-lang-czechslovak texlive-fonts-recommended`, but when i compile my school LaTeX template, this error occurs:

```
LaTeX Error: File `etoolbox.sty' not found
```

Where to find this file? It seems its availible only in newer versions, as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=126614).

Comment: The `etoolbox` package is in `texlive-latex-extra` (probably a missing dependency).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Following the suggestion in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/73017), you can search Debian's database to find the file `etoolbox.sty`. The [search for squeeze](http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=etoolbox.sty) points to the [`texlive-latex-extra`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/texlive-latex-extra) package.

Comment: The texlive-latex-extra package is 868Mo. Is there any way to install it separately?

Comment: @ClémentRenaud You can of course do a stand-alone install of the package (`etoolbox`) by downloading from CTAN, but that is outside of your package manager so may not be what you want to do. WE have a few questions in that area, for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: You can also just launch this command line : sudo apt-get install etoolbox But you'll have to install one by one any other extra package you want to use for Latex. Use this command line to insall most of the Latex extra packages (including etoolbox) sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra