# Installing non-ctan package tikz-dsp.sty using TeXLive tlmgr

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I have installed TeXLive 2012 and have access to `tlmgr` from the command line.  I'd like to know how I can install this `tikz-dsp.sty` that I have downloaded from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/).  I'm assuming I'd use `tlmgr` to do it.  I've tried

```
sudo tlmgr install tikz-dsp.sty
```

however that doesn't work.  The package is not avaliable on CTAN as far as I can tell. I simply downloaded [tikz-dsp](http://www.texample.net/media/tikz/examples/zip/tikz-dsp.zip) from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fir-filter/) and now I want to install it rather than have to copy it to the folder of every latex report I wish to write.

Comment: You can not use `tlmgr` to install packages that are not part of TeXLive. For manuell installation, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system