# How to install my own .cls file on Debian?

Tags: installing, debian

I install texlive with a `.iso` file but not the Debian package.
As on Ubuntu, I will do

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.texmf/tex/latex/amazing
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr conf texmf TEXMFHOME $HOME/.texmf
mv amazingbook.cls $HOME/.texmf/tex/latex/amazing
mktexlsr $HOME/.texmf
```

But this does not help on Debian, i.e. the `latex` can not find `amazingbook.cls`. What should I do then?

Comment: What do you mean 'does not help'? You do know that you don't have to hash your local tree (assuming it's not an NFS mount)?

Comment: Did you install the debian texlive package? or a manual texlive install to /usr/local?

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks! I do not know.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134377/14103) should help.

Comment: If you installed TeX Live using an `.iso` from upstream, you do not need (and ought not) run that `sudo` command. TL will recognise TEXMFHOME already. And don't run `mktexlsr` on it. It is unnecessary and will only confuse things. I *think*, though I am not certain, that TeX may use the database if it is there and that will prevent it finding other things. You don't need or want it for TEXMFHOME. (In 99% of cases.) Don't run the `tlmgr` step. In any case, TEXMFHOME should be `~/texmf` - it is NOT a dot file.

Comment: @MMA Thanks! I do the 8 point in that answer. But it does not help also.

Comment: @cfr Thanks so much! Should I change the TEXMFHOME to default? And how?

Comment: Yes. I don't know. I don't want to suggest something which will make it worse. From the man page concerning using `tlmgr conf` to set rather than merely read options: `Warning: The general facility is here, but tinkering with settings in this way is very strongly discouraged.  Again, no error checking is done, so any sort of breakage is possible.`

Comment: @cfr Hi, I reset TEXMFHOME to `~/texmf` and then `mktexlsr`. Afterwards, it works! Could you explain why _TEXMFHOME should be ~/texmf - it is NOT a dot file_ as an answer? Then I will accept it to end this post.

Comment: @user25607 Done... I spun it out a little, but basically that's all there is to it ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeX Live automatically sets up `~/texmf` as TEXMFHOME. Note that ***it is not a dot file***. Moreover, you should not run `mktexlsr` on this directory. By default - and in 99% of cases, it is a good default - TeX searches the disk directly in that case. This means you can add things and they'll be found right away. Because you probably have a relatively small number of files there, the inconvenience of updating a filename database vastly outweighs any tiny improvement in speed it would yield.

So just put your files under `~/texmf` in the appropriate sub-directory. No additional set up is required post-installation. TeX Live uses this by default.

Comment: Thanks so much! But [the first answer to the linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71469/texmfhome-setting) suggests `~/.texmf`. Why? If I install TL with Debian package, would `~/.texmf` works?

Comment: @user25607 in this case, OP wanted to make invisible. This is not the default; read carefully.

Comment: @SeanAllred Where is invisibility mentioned? Maybe I'm missing the obvious but as far as I can tell, the question is just about how to install a `.cls` file. No mention about making TEXMFHOME invisible.

Comment: @cfr Hi, your answer is enough. But it will be better if we can make TEXMFHOME invisible.

Comment: @user25607 Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83829/39222 help?

Comment: @cfr "I use texlive 2012 on ubuntu 12.04. I wanted my ~/texmf folder invisible, so I edited my texmf.cnf file which is in /usr/local/texlive/2012 directory:

TEXMFHOME = ~/.texmf"

Comment: @SeanAllred Is that in another question? I'm completely lost - I don't see that anywhere on this page. I even ran a search in my browser to convince myself I'm going nuts. The only occurrences of 'invisible' my browser finds are in the comments following my answer. Nothing in the question or comments on it.

Comment: @cfr See the question linked to in OP's first comment on this answer.

Comment: @SeanAllred Oh. I just realised that the 'read carefully' was (I think) not addressed to me. I thought you were saying I had not read *this* question carefully and that *this* OP had said they wanted to make the directory invisible (originally - not just in the comments here). Sorry for the (I think) confusion).

Comment: XD no worries! I could/should have been more specific :)

Comment: @SeanAllred And I should have read your comment more carefully ;). 'XD' ?

Comment: :) (And it's another emoticon; `:) :D XD`)

Comment: But the method in the question is OK for the Ubuntu OS where the Texlive is also installed with a `.iso` file.