# Texmaker Package Management for Linux

Tags: texmaker, linux

I'm using Texmaker on Linux Mint 15. I previously used Texmaker on Windows, with the MiKTeX package manager to automatically download required packages for me. Is there a similar tool I can use on Mint?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, take a look at  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system

Comment: You should install the [full distribution of TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Comment: Note that your TeX system (TeX Live) is not tied to your editor (Texmaker).