# I do not know the key

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={unicode,bookmarks=true}, clock,fragile]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab,pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,
shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,decorations.pathmorphing,
shapes,decorations.text,trees,positioning,datavisualization}
\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepgflibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\datavisualization [ scientific axes=clean,
y axis=grid,
visualize as smooth line/.list={sin,cos,tan},
style sheet=strong colors,
style sheet=vary dashing,
sin={label in legend={text=$\sin x$}},
cos={label in legend={text=$\cos x$}},
tan={label in legend={text=$\tan x$}},
data/format=function ]
data [set=sin] {
var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
func y = sin(\value x r);
}
data [set=cos] {
var x : interval [-0.5*pi:4];
func y = cos(\value x r);
}
data [set=tan] {
var x : interval [-0.3*pi:.3*pi];
func y = tan(\value x r);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But when run pdfLatex I get"! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/data visualization/style
sheet'" How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: This is 'works for me' with an up to date TeX Live 2014. Can you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the results `File list` in the question? (BTW, you might also minimise your example further: I suspect things like `beamer` and Vietnamese text are not relevant to the problem.)

Comment: Put `\pgfversion` in your document and make sure it is v3.00. Data visualization is a recent feature. The code works on my computer.

Comment: My version is 2.1. I just get v3.0. How to change my version from 2.1 to 3.0? I uses texmaker. Thanks.

Comment: Texmaker doesn't really have anything to do with that, which distribution do you have? MikTeX, TeX Live, MacTeX, ...

Comment: I uses Tex Live.

Comment: You don't say which version of TeX Live, but it's not the latest version. Personally, I think I would install TeX Live 2014, which will include PGF 3.0, and the newest versions of  a bunch of other packages. If you're on Ubuntu or similar, see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373) for instructions. If you're on Windows, just install as usual. Alternatively, if you downloaded the `.tds.zip` file from SourceForge, see method 3 in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017) for intruction

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem caused by outdated packages (`pgf`, in this case).