# How to install eqexam

Tags: installing

I see that the `eqexam` is available at `CTAN` ([here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eqexam)). But when I run:

```
sudo tlmgr install eqexam
```

I receive the following message:

```
package eqexam not present in package repository.
```

How can I install it?

Comment: I think you may want to have a look to [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/13304).

Comment: Thanks. That's fine and it helped. I wonder: if it's on `CTAN`, how come I cannot install it with `tlmgr`?

Comment: @NVaughan: Not any package on CTAN is available for TeXLive. This depends on the license specified by the package author(s). `eqexam` is such a package, as far as I know.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't know that.