# How to update TeX Live packages?

Tags: packages, texlive

I was trying to compile a document which includes the package
[`multiaudience`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience?lang=en).
Unfortunately, it seems that the version of TeX Live which I have installed is too old.
I can tell from the multiaudience documentation that
v1.02 was released on the date 2015/08/02.
The output of running `pdflatex` shows that my LaTeX2e version
is dated 2015/01/01.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multiaudience}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Student slide 1}
blah blah blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output from compiling it the document.

```
$ pdflatex main
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015 (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
...
! LaTeX Error: File `multiaudience.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

Is there a way to update my TeX Live packages?

Comment: `tlmgr update --self --all` will update first TeX Live Manager and then all packages.

Comment: You may have to install it, `tlmgr install multiaudience`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This works for me. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459) and [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017)

Comment: Nope, duplicate of one of the above.