# Why doesn't TikZ/pgf's \foreach[remember] work with explicit lists?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

The short version: when using `\foreach \x in [remember=\x as \lastx]`, iterating `in {1,...,3}` works, but iterating `in {1,2,3}` doesn't.

I have read the manual paragraph on `/pgf/foreach/remember` but don't see anything indicating why this should be the case.

This is particularly troubling when iterating over multiple numeric variables, where `x0/y0,...,xn/yn` doesn't seem to work anyway. Of course, it's also a problem when your list just *doesn't* follow an arithmetic sequence.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}  % same outcome with article

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) node[above] {
    \foreach \x [
      remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)
    ] in {1,2,3}
    {\x, \lastx;\quad}
  };
  \draw (0, -1) node[above] {
    \foreach \x [
      remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0)
    ] in {1,...,3}
    {\x, \lastx;\quad}
  };
  \draw (0, -2) node[above] {
    \foreach \x / \y [
      remember=\x as \lastx (initially 0),
      remember=\y as \lasty (initially 0),
    ] in {1/11,2/22,3/13}
    {$(\x,\y), (\lastx,\lasty)$;\quad}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output: top line says "1, 0; 2, 0; 3, 0" (wrong); second line says "1, 0; 2, 1; 3, 2" (right); bottom line says "(1, 11), (0, 0); (2, 22), (0, 0); (3, 33), (0, 0)" (wrong, and no way to fix by converting to <code>...</code> notation))]

I'd be inclined to deem this a bug if it weren't such a prevalent use case…

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your outcome with your MWE. I get `1,0; 2,1; 3,2;` for the first node and `(1,11),(0,0); (2,22),(1,11); (3,13),(2,22);` for the last.

Comment: Which version of  `pgf`/TikZ do you have, your example works fine here with v3.0.1a.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Looks like I'm on `pgf 2008/01/05 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)`, which seems quite old, but I'm using TeX Live 2013, which isn't *that* old. Is there an easy way to update without confusing `apt`?

Comment: There was no major update for TikZ between 2.10 and 3.0 which came out in december 2013 if memory serves me right. Not really an expert on such things, I usually just install the latest TeX Live straight from TUG.org (see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)), and update packages with `tlmgr`. More info on updating/installing packages can be found in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating TikZ/PGF to a recent version.