# tikz \addlegendentry leading to error for certain plots

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

Using Emacs/Auctex under Ubuntu 14.04 (TexLive 2012) I get the following error

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
--- TeX said ---
<argument>
\pgfplots@current@point@x,\pgfplots@current@point@y,\pgfplots@c...
l.2268 \end{axis}
```

on including `\addlegendentry{blabla}` in a tikz file. Interestingly the error only occurs for 3D plots (I use matlab2tikz to generate the tikz file from Matlab figures) and 2D plots work fine. Furthermore, a correct PDF is generated despite the error and I do not get the error when using TexShop on OSX (TexLive 2014). Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering 
    \newlength\figureheight 
    \newlength\figurewidth  
    \caption{This is an example}  
    \input{mwe.tikz} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

where the mwe.tikz is the following

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=2.898in,
height=3.549in,
at={(0.486in,0.479in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-1,
xmax=1,
tick align=outside,
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-1,
ymax=1,
ymajorgrids,
zmin=-1,
zmax=1,
zmajorgrids,
view={-37.5}{30},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,    
axis y line*=left,
axis z line*=left,
legend style={at={(1.03,1)},anchor=north west,legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black}
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=flat corner,draw=black,z buffer=sort,colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.2081,0.1663,0.5292); rgb(1pt)=(0.211624,0.189781,0.577676); rgb(2pt)=(0.212252,0.213771,0.626971); rgb(3pt)=(0.2081,0.2386,0.677086); rgb(4pt)=(0.195905,0.264457,0.7279); rgb(5pt)=(0.170729,0.291938,0.779248); rgb(6pt)=(0.125271,0.324243,0.830271); rgb(7pt)=(0.0591333,0.359833,0.868333); rgb(8pt)=(0.0116952,0.38751,0.881957); rgb(9pt)=(0.00595714,0.408614,0.882843); rgb(10pt)=(0.0165143,0.4266,0.878633); rgb(11pt)=(0.0328524,0.443043,0.871957); rgb(12pt)=(0.0498143,0.458571,0.864057); rgb(13pt)=(0.0629333,0.47369,0.855438); rgb(14pt)=(0.0722667,0.488667,0.8467); rgb(15pt)=(0.0779429,0.503986,0.838371); rgb(16pt)=(0.0793476,0.520024,0.831181); rgb(17pt)=(0.0749429,0.537543,0.826271); rgb(18pt)=(0.0640571,0.556986,0.823957); rgb(19pt)=(0.0487714,0.577224,0.822829); rgb(20pt)=(0.0343429,0.596581,0.819852); rgb(21pt)=(0.0265,0.6137,0.8135); rgb(22pt)=(0.0238905,0.628662,0.803762); rgb(23pt)=(0.0230905,0.641786,0.791267); rgb(24pt)=(0.0227714,0.653486,0.776757); rgb(25pt)=(0.0266619,0.664195,0.760719); rgb(26pt)=(0.0383714,0.674271,0.743552); rgb(27pt)=(0.0589714,0.683757,0.725386); rgb(28pt)=(0.0843,0.692833,0.706167); rgb(29pt)=(0.113295,0.7015,0.685857); rgb(30pt)=(0.145271,0.709757,0.664629); rgb(31pt)=(0.180133,0.717657,0.642433); rgb(32pt)=(0.217829,0.725043,0.619262); rgb(33pt)=(0.258643,0.731714,0.595429); rgb(34pt)=(0.302171,0.737605,0.571186); rgb(35pt)=(0.348167,0.742433,0.547267); rgb(36pt)=(0.395257,0.7459,0.524443); rgb(37pt)=(0.44201,0.748081,0.503314); rgb(38pt)=(0.487124,0.749062,0.483976); rgb(39pt)=(0.530029,0.749114,0.466114); rgb(40pt)=(0.570857,0.748519,0.44939); rgb(41pt)=(0.609852,0.747314,0.433686); rgb(42pt)=(0.6473,0.7456,0.4188); rgb(43pt)=(0.683419,0.743476,0.404433); rgb(44pt)=(0.71841,0.741133,0.390476); rgb(45pt)=(0.752486,0.7384,0.376814); rgb(46pt)=(0.785843,0.735567,0.363271); rgb(47pt)=(0.818505,0.732733,0.34979); rgb(48pt)=(0.850657,0.7299,0.336029); rgb(49pt)=(0.882433,0.727433,0.3217); rgb(50pt)=(0.913933,0.725786,0.306276); rgb(51pt)=(0.944957,0.726114,0.288643); rgb(52pt)=(0.973895,0.731395,0.266648); rgb(53pt)=(0.993771,0.745457,0.240348); rgb(54pt)=(0.999043,0.765314,0.216414); rgb(55pt)=(0.995533,0.786057,0.196652); rgb(56pt)=(0.988,0.8066,0.179367); rgb(57pt)=(0.978857,0.827143,0.163314); rgb(58pt)=(0.9697,0.848138,0.147452); rgb(59pt)=(0.962586,0.870514,0.1309); rgb(60pt)=(0.958871,0.8949,0.113243); rgb(61pt)=(0.959824,0.921833,0.0948381); rgb(62pt)=(0.9661,0.951443,0.0755333); rgb(63pt)=(0.9763,0.9831,0.0538)},mesh/rows=6]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   z   c\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
-0.587785252292473  0   -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
-0.951056516295154  0   -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
-0.951056516295154  0   0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
-0.587785252292473  0   0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
-0.18163563200134   -0.559016994374947  -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
-0.293892626146236  -0.904508497187474  -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
-0.293892626146236  -0.904508497187474  0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
-0.18163563200134   -0.559016994374947  0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
0.475528258147577   -0.345491502812526  -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
0.769420884293813   -0.559016994374947  -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
0.769420884293813   -0.559016994374947  0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
0.475528258147577   -0.345491502812526  0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
0.475528258147577   0.345491502812526   -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
0.769420884293813   0.559016994374947   -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
0.769420884293813   0.559016994374947   0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
0.475528258147577   0.345491502812526   0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
-0.18163563200134   0.559016994374947   -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
-0.293892626146236  0.904508497187474   -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
-0.293892626146236  0.904508497187474   0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
-0.18163563200134   0.559016994374947   0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
0   0   -1  -1\\
-0.587785252292473  0   -0.809016994374947  -0.809016994374947\\
-0.951056516295154  0   -0.309016994374947  -0.309016994374947\\
-0.951056516295154  0   0.309016994374947   0.309016994374947\\
-0.587785252292473  0   0.809016994374947   0.809016994374947\\
0   0   1   1\\
};
\addlegendentry{This is a sphere};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Can somebody tell me what is going on?

Comment: Works fine here, with a recently updated TeX Live 2015.

Comment: On Ubuntu with Emacs/Auctex? So I would just have to upgrade TeX Live to 2015?

Comment: Well, Kubuntu in TeXworks, but that shouldn't matter. I see now that you mention it working in TL 2014 as well. Updating just `pgfplots` (and possibly `pgf`) may well be enough, seeing as no other packages are used. There are some instructions in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016) Personally I never really install packages manually, as I usually install the latest TL (see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373)), and then packages are installed/updated with `tlmgr`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem can be solved by updating pgfplots package.