# \hdashline no longer works

Tags: packages

The command `\hdashline` no longer works.   It appears to be a part of the `arydshln.sty` package and that package is no longer found.    What have I  done?    More importantly, how can I correct it?

Comment: Obviously (!), the package have been removed, so you should re-install it (how to do this depends on your OS).

Comment: I did not knowingly remove the package.   My OS is Mac OS X 10.11.5.     Can you tell me how to re-install the package?    I am a user, not a guru, so please be simplicity explicit.

Comment: This question is about Linux (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system), but its prety much the same on Mac OS X if you are using the TeX Live distro.

Comment: You should do that with `TeX Live Utility`, the version of TeX Live Package Manager  for MacOS.

Comment: My Tex is something called Tex Shop 2.

Comment: That' s  the editor. Your TeX distribution is probably  MacTeX.

Comment: You should post a MWE, otherwise it really is unclear what is happening. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe