# Continuous integration with travis -- package.sty not found

Tags: revision-control, git

I want to use travis-ci on my project on github, [a MWE of which is available here](https://github.com/HughParsonage/travis-latex-ci).

I am using the following `.travis.yml` file, following the steps given in this [Minimal CI LaTeX builder](http://www.chrisandre.org/2015/08/minimal-travis-ci-latex-builder/) site.

```
before_install:
- sudo apt-get update -qq
- sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base
script:
- mkdir build
- pdflatex -output-directory build Example.tex
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: <mykey>
  file: Example.pdf
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: HughParsonage/travis-latex-ci
```

However, when I push a commit, I get the error `scrreprt.cls not found`.

I tried changing the installation to `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra`, but I then get the error `adjustbox.sty not found`.

I understand these errors – the TeX Live distribution I requested travis use does not have the packages/class files I need, but not how to resolve them through a `.travis.yml` file. I understand I could put the respective `.cls/.sty` files in the same directory until I get no build errors. However, is there a way to get all these packages on the travis machine?

Comment: `scrreport` is most likely not included in tex-live-base. I would recommend to do a standard installation of `TeX Live` that contains everything.

Comment: OK, I thought that `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` achieved that, but I still get additional packages. What should I put after `sudo apt-get install`?

Comment: Does a normal TeX file using the class get compiled? I never heard of `adjustbox.sty`. What I generally recommend is not tu use the distribution LaTeX but rather to get TeX Live from tug.org.

Comment: Yes, the class file is fine (at least it compiles without errors on my local machine). I'm using MiKTeX.

Comment: After a long way of testing i found a easy way, using the R-template for travis. This comes with the regular Texlive-distribution and you can install Packets using tlmgr. Have a look at here: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: The LaTeX3 team also uses Travis, see e.g. http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/why-does-it-always-fail-on-me-automating-testing-using-travis-ci/ They install a minimal distribution using the installer from TUG.org I believe, see https://github.com/latex3/latex3 Edit: Have a look at `support/texlive.sh`

Comment: Hmm, I tried copying the code (including `./source`, but I get the error message `"source ./support/texlive.sh"`.

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: @sistlind Thanks, but I tried your `.travis.yml` file and  received the error `The command "make manual-git" exited with 2.`

Comment: Well, you have to provide your own build script. The hint for this travis-file was just for the installation of packages. Have a look at the Makefile of the repository and the deploy.sh file, respectively. There you can find the build commands.

Comment: Ah that was silly of me! Currently building well. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

On a local system it's possible to simply install 'all of TeX Live' and avoid these issues. With a remote test system, where you need to minimise installation size, that is more difficult. (Yes, Travis-CI will cache installed packages but asking for all of TeX Live is probably somewhat extreme.)

As discussed in [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system), it is possible to look up which Ubuntu package contains which `.sty` file (or similar) and thus to debug these issues. However, that is still probably somewhat error prone in running on a 'live' system. I'd therefore recommend setting up a virtual machine which matches the CI system you've chosen: for example, Travis-CI currently use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. You can then test 'locally' (and with access to logs, *etc.*) exactly which packages do and do not need to be installed to make things work.

As noted in comments, for LaTeX3 development we have [set up Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/latex3/latex3), but use a [script](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/support/texlive.sh) which installs 'vanilla' TeX Live rather than using the Ubuntu packaged version. The considerations working this way are much the same: selection of TeX packages which are required with omission of others.  There is no real difference in this sense between testing programming and testing documents: it is still a question of working out what is needed and installing it.

Comment: Do you have any advice how to drive the installation to test *biber* as well? I've tried `sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra` and `sudo apt-get -y install biber`.

Comment: @Hugh The Ubuntu version used by Travis-CI (TL'09) doesn't include Biber. You'll therefore have to go down the 'install vanilla TL' route to test anything that needs this.

Comment: See https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/articles/tb114wright.ltx for the source of a _TUGboat_ I've written on this