# Installing pygments and configuring minted for continuous builds on travis-CI

Tags: minted, build-system, travis, continuous-integration

I have set up a continuous integration system using github and travis CI using [this workflow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398830/how-to-build-my-latex-automatically-using-travis-ci) that was given as an answer to a similar question here. Everything works fine and I am able to build the PDF upon each git push.

Now, there is an issue in using the `minted` package for code listings. which has an external dependency on the `pygments` library.

How do I modify the `.travis.yml` (specifically the one from that reference link) to install `pygments` on the travis build environment and configure it (i.e. make TeX find it) for building the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about Travis in particular, but there is another docker image (vanilla TL2018 on Debian) out there that works with minted and Pygments: `sumdoc/texlive-2018` (see https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2018/). Simply use this as a replacement for your previous docker image and you will be able to run a normal LaTeX call with shell escape to build your document.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Travis-specific answer: you can install such dependencies by adding this to your `.travis.yml` before the `install` block:

```
# Dependency of the minted package
before_install:
 - sudo apt-get install python-pygments
```