# How can I run biber on travis-ci?

Tags: biblatex, biber, continuous-integration, travis

I succesfully build a latex document using instructions from [How to build my LaTeX automatically using Travis CI?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398830/how-to-build-my-latex-automatically-using-travis-ci/398831#comment1135069_398831) and save the pdf in a github release.
I use the tectronic docker image of @rekka.

However now that my latex document uses biber/biblatex the cites and \printbibliography doesnt work when produced by travis (locally it works running lualatex, biber, lualatex, lualatex).

I assume biber is not run on travis. Does someone know how I can run biber on travis?

PS: Forgive me if I got something wrong, im rather a LaTeX-Beginner

EDIT: My .travis.yml looks like this:

```
sudo: required
services: docker
script:
- docker pull rekka/tectonic
- docker run --mount src=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR,target=/usr/src/tex,type=bind rekka/tectonic
  tectonic main.tex
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [long API key]
  file: main.pdf
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: [my-repo]
```

EDIT2: @moewe found this github issue https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/issues/35 which is asking for biblatex support on tectronic. However question remains the same (allthough not necessary with tectronic anymore).

Comment: The `.travis.yml` in the linked answer ends with `- travis_wait 3 pdflatex -output-directory _build ./src/nameofmytexfile.tex` did you try to add a Biber call there? You can make your life *much* easier if you don't use a build directory (`-output-directory`). Remember that you need to run `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please show your build file here? Maybe you could simply run arara on Travis and specify the instructions in your file.

Comment: You will have to tell tectonic to run Biber for you. I have never heard of it and I could not find documentation, so I guess you have a better chance of getting an answer at https://tectonic.newton.cx/

Comment: Of course it is also possible that something else is going wrong, but to diagnose that we would need to see the `.log` and `.blg` files.

Comment: @moewe I can only show you the log of travis see here https://pastebin.com/dpsH0VRw
Maybe its possible to copy .log and .blg file to the github release.

Comment: https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/issues/35 suggests Biber is not supported in tectonic yet. Apparently there are workarounds: https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/issues/53, https://malramsay.com/post/compiling_latex_on_travis/

Comment: What about https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2018/?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to this various links. I found out about issue 53 and its probably a lot of work to download binaries and integrate them (I guess). Texlive full distro is too big (3gb on each build). But the malramsay link is promising.
I also found https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf#1b-miniconda-with-tectonic this one promising. Let you know how it turns out

Comment: @moewe https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf#1b-miniconda-with-tectonic Didnt work, I got an error on compilation of my tex file, which I didnt investigate further. Also build took 4 times longer.

https://malramsay.com/post/compiling_latex_on_travis/ did work flawlessly. I havent made any cites yet, but soon as I do I will post it as answer. Buildtitme has almost tripled, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I build [a docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/dxjoke/tectonic-docker/) which includes tectonic and biber. (Based of @rekka's image and this [information](https://malramsay.com/post/compiling_latex_on_travis/)).

Basically [these commands](https://github.com/tectonic-typesetting/tectonic/issues/53#issuecomment-404370890) are ran inside the container (which you can see in the .travis.yml) :

```
tectonic --keep-intermediates --reruns 0 main.tex
biber main
tectonic main.tex
```

The .travis.yml looks now like this:

```
sudo: required
services: docker
script:
- docker pull dxjoke/tectonic-docker
- docker run --mount src=$TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR,target=/usr/src/tex,type=bind dxjoke/tectonic-docker
  /bin/sh -c "tectonic --keep-intermediates --reruns 0 main.tex; biber main; tectonic main.tex"
deploy:
  provider: releases
  api_key:
    secure: [long api key]
  file: main.pdf
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    repo: [myrepo]
```