# bibtex fails in travis but runs locally

Tags: bibtex, continuous-integration, travis

I created a `build.sh` file which runs `xelatex` and `bibtex` to build the pdf file.

In my `.travis.yml` I put this script to test my repository. Locally, the build runs fine, but on Travis I get a bibtex error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian)

The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux

A level-1 auxiliary file: title/cover.aux

A level-1 auxiliary file: title/title.aux

I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis.aux

I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux

I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux

(There were 3 error messages)
```

My `build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error thesis.tex
bibtex thesis.aux
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error thesis.tex
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error thesis.tex
```

And finally, the `.travis.yml`:

```
language: shell
os: linux

install:
- sudo apt-get -qq update && sudo apt-get -qq -y install texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-full texlive-xetex texlive-pstricks

script:
- ./build.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you actually have citation commands in your `.tex` file? Do you get the same error when running BibTeX locally? Note that you can also run `latexmk -xelatex`, then it is automatically determined if you need BibTeX or not and how many times XeLaTeX needs to run.

Comment: I do have citation commands in tex files which I `\input` in `thesis.tex`. When running locally, bibtex recognizes other `.aux` files and doesn't throw an error.
Thank you for the `latexmk` hint!

Comment: Maybe you can simplify the situation a bit (for testing) by moving all citation related things into the main file, or by removing the `bibtex` call from the build script, and check if all content is properly input? Then you can see if it is a problem related to input files or if the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Even though I don't know what the error is here, TeX Live 2015 is perhaps old compared to your local system. I wrote other methods of building LaTeX on Travis here, perhaps they could be helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398831/98850 (or on [github](https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf) (In particular [this one](https://github.com/PHPirates/travis-ci-latex-pdf#pdflatex))).

Comment: About this particular error: a minimal LaTeX document would be helpful (or a link to your repo with the file, if it's open source)

Comment: Here's a link to the [Github repository](https://github.com/LorenzBung/bachelor-thesis), with the build, tex and travis files in the root of the repo

Comment: put `cat thesis.aux` before the bibtex call then the travis log will show the aux file. Are there any \citation commands in the aux? if not did you get an error in the  xetex run that prevented the aux file being written?

Comment: possibly not related but never use `\include` in the preamble. `\include{header/header}` should be `\input{header/header}`

Comment: I do not see any `\cite` in that repository?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In the last line of `title/extended_abstract.tex`. Thanks for the note on the `\include`, I'm still learning a lot!

Comment: so there is meanwhile never use either of these lines with xetex `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` The first is positvely harmful, the second does nothing (with a warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed the issue with help of [David's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533388/bibtex-fails-in-travis-but-runs-locally#comment1348976_533388): I removed the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` when building with `latexmk -xelatex`, which let the build pass successfully.