# How I can install the imsart package?

Tags: packages, texlive

I need to install the `imsart` package to submit my article to an IMS journal. I downloaded the zip file from the [IMS website](http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html), but I do not know how to install this package. I want to install this package so I can use it in Scientific WorkPlace and Texmaker.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Next time provide a bit more information, such as: whether you are using Windows or Linux and the TeX distribution used etc. Nonetheless, just follow the appropriate links given below, in that order:
1. [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/78565)
2. [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/78565)
3. [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/78565)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't install the package on my system, but instead copy the relevant files into the same folder as the main LaTeX document. That way, you can ensure that any colleagues working on the paper use the same IMS template, and not maybe some old version - or even run into issues with compiling, as they didn't install the template either.

Also, the [imsart FAQ](http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/imsart-faq.html) says that, if you want to upload your paper to arXiv, you need to upload `imsart.sty` (and I assume also `imsart.cls`) as well. You'll thus have to have this file ready for uploading anyways, and if you have it right in your working folder, you hopefully won't forget to upload it.

So, the fastest way to get started is to unzip the archive, copy it to your favourite folder, rename the folder to e.g. `myAwesomePaper`, rename the `ims-template.tex` to e.g. `myPaper.tex`, and start working on that file.

If you *do* want to install the package on your system, e.g. if you write IMS papers all the time, and don't want to bother copying the files around every time, then [this TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) tells you exactly where to place the package files. Just copy the content of the zip archive to that place, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. But when I use your advice I receive this message: Process started
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\farsitex\config\miktex.ini: cannot read
personal configuration
Process exited with error(s)
@hbaderts

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you run `pdflatex myPaper.tex`? Are you able to compile other simple documents?

Comment: yes I  ran [link](pdflatex mypaper.tex) . I am not able to run any document. @hbaderts

Comment: I think my problem came from texlive and texmaker installation problems. I uninstalled them and reinstalled again. In this way I could run my document. Thank you @hbaderts