# Error in TexStudio

Tags: installing, document-classes

I started using latex in Ubuntu 14.4 with Texstudio editor. In windows i didn't get any error for the same document, but in Ubuntu i get many errors.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  \usepackage{cite}
\fi

\begin{document}

hello testing


% make the title area
\maketitle

% As a general rule, do not put math, special symbols or citations
% in the abstract

\end{document}
```

> File `IEEEtran.cls' not found. \usepackage

Comment: TeXLive in Ubuntu is a complicated matter, it is spread out into many many Ubuntu packages, and it is har to know which Ubuntu package provides which LaTeX file. Either install all Ubuntu TeXLive (`texlive-full`), or install `apt-file` and use it to search for which Ubuntu package provides `IEEEtran.cls` or install upstream TeXLive (tug.org/texlive) manually.

Comment: At least on my Ubuntu (old one) `apt-file search IEEEtran.cls` returns `texlive-publishers`

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: If you have the possibilities, I would not use the build in ubuntu linux but install a complete up-to-date texlive.

Comment: @samcarter aren't you refering til the **build in ubuntu texlive**, bit hard to ewmove the build in Linux from Ubuntu ;-)

Comment: @daleif yeah, of course you are right. Ubuntu without linux would be ... interesting :)

Comment: Is there any news here?