# Tex Live 2016: Install package

Tags: packages, texlive-2016

The question is specific to Tex Live 2016.

I use Tex Live 2016:

```
tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)
```

Upon running

```
pdflatex file.tex
```

I encounter an error of this type

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pgf-pie.sty' not found.
```

How to install a package in Tex Live 2016?

Comment: `pgf-pie.sty` is not part of TeX Live. You have to download it from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-pie and [install if manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/73017).

Comment: Note that it is not in TeXLive as it has no license (see the CTAN link Schweinebacke provided), TL is rather strict on licenses. Which is a bit stange as the googlecode homepage for it lists an MIT license, but the Author did not mention this in the STY file. Might be an idea to write the author.

Comment: The manual install worked

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by manual package installation as mentioned in the comments.