# How to install package

Tags: installing

When I compile my tex file, it returns a wrong,
"File `microtype.sty' not found. \usepackage"

How can I solve it?

Comment: Use you TeX distribution's package manager to install the package. Or, make life easy for yourself and either install a complete distribution or (if using MikTeX) set things up for on-the-fly package installation.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but I don't know what of because there's too little information. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system