# Installing "tikz-ladder" library

Tags: tikzlibrary

I am new here. Before I decided to ask this question I spent a few hours looking for an answer on my own.

I'm trying to include the "tikz-lad­der" ( https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ladder ) library to my document using:

```
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{circuits}
 \usetikzlibrary{circuits.plc.ladder}
```

Tex says that it can't find the library. I'm trying to install it through TexLive but I can't the "tikz-ladder" package.

I'm using TeXStudio under Fedora 27. By "TexLive" I mean typing "dnf install texlive-" into terminal. I've already installed "texlive-full" and "texlive-tikz*" through "my TexLive".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a workaround, you could manually install it either in your current directory or your texmf folder from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-ladder (see  also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: Do you have updated your package manager?  have you tried with the following command `tlmgr update --self` and then `tlmgr install pkgname`. if wou need some automated and friendly graphicaly option, you could change to Miktex, its only a suggestion, it could not mean that one is better than other.

Answer (score 1):

Download `pgfmanual-en-macros.tex` from
[CTAN](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/pstring/pgfmanual-en-macros.tex) and put it in your working directory.

Go to [tikz-ladder on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ladder) and the file `tikzlibrarycircuits.plc.ladder.code` is at `tex` folder of `tikz-ladder`. Copy it and put it in your working directory. In my case, this was the solution:

Use the following before your code. These need not be in preamble.

```
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros}    
\input{tikzlibrarycircuits.plc.ladder.code}
```

Sample Codes

```
\input{pgfmanual-en-macros}
\input {tikzlibrarycircuits.plc.ladder.code}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit plc ladder,thick,ladderrungsep=0.8]
\draw(0,0) 
    to [contact NO={info={$A$},name=ca}] ++(3,0)
    to [coil={info={$Q$}}] ++(3,0) coordinate(laddertopright);
ill[red!20] (laddertopright |- ca.south) rectangle +(-2,-1em);
  \draw(0,-1) 
    to [contact NO={info={$B$},name=cb}] ++(3,0) -- +(0,1);
  ill[red!20] (laddertopright |- cb.south) 
       rectangle +(-2,-1em) coordinate (pb);
  ill[blue!20] (pb) rectangle ++(2,-0.8);
\ladderrungend{2}
  \draw(0,0) 
    to [contact NO={info={$C$},name=cc}] ++(3,0)
    to [coil={info={$R$}}] ++(3,0);
  ill[red!20] (laddertopright |- cc.south) 
       rectangle +(-2,-1em) coordinate (pc);
  ill[blue!20] (pc) rectangle ++(2,-0.8);
\ladderrungend{1}
  \draw(0,0) 
    to [contact NO={info={$D$}}] ++(3,0)
    to [coil={info={$S$}}] ++(3,0);
\ladderrungend{1}
\ladderpowerrails
\end{tikzpicture}
```