# latex compilation via php's shell_exec

Tags: compiling, latexmk, php

I want to compile a latex file via php. Therefore I use

`shell_exec("/usr/bin/xelatex --output-directory=output/ --interaction batchmode doc.tex");`

The problem I ran into is that the www-data user on my Apache webserver is not able to use some installed LaTeX packages.
I believe (but I'm not sure) it has something to do with a home dir. And my www-data has none (or so I think).

By the way, I use TexLive on the server.

Edit: Here's my code of the php compiling

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.6.16)  18 JUN 2018 07:13
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**/var/www/html/tennessee/wp-content/plugins/daw_songbook/tmp/doc.tex
(/var/www/html/tennessee/wp-content/plugins/daw_songbook/tmp/doc.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 8 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)

! LaTeX Error: File `songs.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.5 \usepackage
               {amsmath}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 225 strings out of 494938
 2641 string characters out of 6176411
 55952 words of memory out of 5000000
 4170 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 22i,0n,19p,169b,40s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: Could you please show us how you came to your conclusion with the inability to use some packages?

Comment: I tried to compile the same file with several "normal" users and with sudo on the server. Everytime with success. And I found a copy of the used installed packages in the Home dirs.

Comment: Can you obtain the `.log` file of the XeLaTeX run?

Comment: Yes I do. The logfile says, that the package.sty is not found. So a pdf is not created.

Comment: With TeX Live there should not be any installed packages in the home directory (if you have a proper server installation). So something on your setup is non-standard. Could you maybe post your log file here?

Comment: Why is the first package you want to load `songs`? Are you sure you need it?

Comment: I just checked the log after compiling successfully via command line as a user. There I found out, that the specific package really is located in my Home Dir... I don't get it. I installed it with tlmgr.

Comment: the songs package is essential for the document.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I did it.

tlmgr installs packages only in the home dir of the users. That is a problem, because when I want php to compile it via shell_exec, the www-data user of my server does not have the package.

So instead of installing it via     tlmgr      I installed it manually in     /tex/latex/     and after that I run     mktexlsr    .

The www-data user does now search and find the package in the global base dir and not inside a local home dir.

Thanks to the following link (Method 3):
[How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: You should still use tlmgr, but as root, so that it will be in global scope.

Comment: I'd also have thought that if `tlmgr` is run as root it would install packages for all users in the shared directory and not in home. Letting `tlmgr` manage things instead of installing manually is normally the infinitely better choice.

Comment: I am running into the same problem. So I need to copy a ton of stuff to the system-wide file?