# Running bashful on Windows

Tags: tex-core, bashful

Since the author of the package `\bashful` claims:

> The pack­age may use other Unix shells than bash, but does not work
>   with­out mod­i­fi­ca­tion in a Win­dows en­vi­ron­ment.
>   https://ctan.org/pkg/bashful

... I'm wondering what kind of modification this will be.

When I try to run the simple mwe (with shell-escape on a Windows-system using cmd or Power-Shell):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\bash
ls
\END
\end{document}
```

... all I get is this error:

> ! This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
>   ! (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>   ! (./minimal.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
>   ! article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bashful/bashful.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)))
>   ! (./minimal.aux) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
>   ! [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )**Der Befehl
>   ! "bash" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden
>   ! werden.** system returned with code 1
>   ! 
>   ! L6: I will now print the contents of file minimal.stderr (if found)
>   ! L6: File minimal.stderr was empty L6: Proceeding as usual L6: Checking
>   ! whether any listings are required L6: Nothing has to be listed L6:
>   ! Defining macro for the contents of the standard output file L6: Opened
>   ! file minimal.stdout L6: File minimal.stdoutwas empty after EOF L6:
>   ! bashStdout := \bashStdout
>   ! 
>   ! L6: Closing file minimal.stdout L6: Defining macro for the contents of
>   ! the standard error file L6: Opened file minimal.stderr L6: File
>   ! minimal.stdoutwas empty ! Undefined control sequence. 
>   ! ...nputlineno : bashStderr := \bashStderr
>   ! 
>   ! l.6 \END
>   !         ^^M ? L6: bashStderr :=
>   ! 
>   ! 
>   ! L6: Closing file minimal.stderr L6: Wrap up done L6: bashV: Done!
>   ! (./minimal.aux) ) No pages of output. Transcript written on
>   ! minimal.log. PS
>   ! D:\OneDrive\Dokumente__Projekte\TEX_Bilderliste\minimal> PS
>   ! D:\OneDrive\Dokumente__Projekte\TEX_Bilderliste\minimal> pdflatex
>   ! -shell-escape minimal.tex This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>   ! (./minimal.tex LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
>   ! article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bashful/bashful.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu)))
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg)))
>   ! (./minimal.aux) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
>   ! (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
>   ! [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )Der Befehl
>   ! "bash" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden
>   ! werden. system returned with code 1
>   ! 
>   ! L6: I will now print the contents of file minimal.stderr (if found)
>   ! L6: File minimal.stderr was empty L6: Proceeding as usual L6: Checking
>   ! whether any listings are required L6: Nothing has to be listed L6:
>   ! Defining macro for the contents of the standard output file L6: Opened
>   ! file minimal.stdout L6: File minimal.stdoutwas empty after EOF L6:
>   ! bashStdout := \bashStdout
>   !
>   ! L6: Closing file minimal.stdout L6: Defining macro for the contents of
>   ! the standard error file L6: Opened file minimal.stderr L6: File
>   ! minimal.stdoutwas empty ! Undefined control sequence. 
>   ! ...nputlineno : bashStderr := \bashStderr
>   ! 
>   ! l.6 \END
>   !         ^^M ?

The highlighted part means: **The command "bash" is either misspelled or could not be found.** This indicates that there is a very essential problem with the setup, right?

Can anyone please shed some light? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Windows does not use bash or anything shell-alike (in the unix sense). The easiest solution would be to install bash for windows.

Comment: Thank you Texnician. Installing `bash` does the trick. I also installed latex and the `\bashful` package within the bash and it now runs like a charm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments

Comment: I'm voting to *not* close this question, as it still would be interesting if or how a native solution for a port of this package to Windows systems would look like

Comment: I agree with siracusa. @バニーダーク Would you be willing to write up an answer how you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'd like to highlight that this would be a *Windows-10*-way only, since you have to activate some Windows-10-specific things.
Windows 8 & 7 etc. users have to look for corresponding tutorials.

As @Texnician mentioned:

> Windows does not use bash or anything shell-alike (in the unix sense).

## 1. Installing Bash for Windows

- get access to the *Windows settings*:  *WIN + I*

  - *Update and Security*
  - *For Developers*
  - activate *Developer Mode*
- get access to your *Control Panel*

  - *Programs*
  - *Turn Windows features on or off*
  - activate *Windows-subsystem for Linux*

What we get is a ubuntu-bash by canonical.

WIN + type "bash" will open the bash terminal.

Alternatively
- cmd: type "bash"
- Powershell: type "bash"

## 2. Installing Latex (TeX Live)

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-base
```

### 2.1 Install \bashul package

*Since I'm not a Linux user at all I just followed the suggestions that were made in this thread [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) There might be a better way to get `\bashful`.* *blush*

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra --no-install-recommends
```

## 3. Utilize `\bashful`

- study the package documentaion http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/bashful/bashful.pdf
- render your tex document with the argument *-shell-escape*