# How do I fix tlmgr error and install tikz-network.sty?

Tags: tlmgr

I use latex a lot.  I want to install tikz-network.  Here are a couple of command lines and their results.

```
$ tlmgr --version
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr revision 46207 (2018-01-04 19:34:36 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017

# tlmgr install tikz-network
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

$ tlmgr update all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

$ update-tlmgr-latest --update
update-tlmgr-latest: command not found
```

Comment: Your Debian texlive is version 2017 and thus cannot be updated via tlmgr, you will need texlive 2019 for that.

Comment: So, must I uninstall texlive and reinstall via synaptic?  If not that, what is the preferred way?

Comment: You can look up online if anyone has a Debian repo for texlive  2019, they often tend to be rather behind. Though I know Norbert is making it for Debian. Personally, I tend to never get latex from a Linux dist, as mentioned they then to be behind in updates, so I use the so-called upstream version directly from tug. It also have the benefit of the un modified tlmgr (I think Debian make it install into user setup, upstream installs into base system)

Comment: Apologies.  So many different pages give so much different advice on what to do that I do not know how to choose a path.  Not because I haven't tried but because all efforts have failed.  Please provide a link to a known good texlive process for removing 2017 and installing 2019.  I've tried about a dozen pages and found nothing clear and complete.

Comment: As mentioned I use the upstream texlive manually install, so I cannot help you there

Comment: `tikz-network` is a package that can easily be installed manually, the `.sty` file is provided on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-network). You can download it from there and put it either in the folder where you store your document (which allows you to use the package only for documents in that folder) or copy it into the `texmf` tree to make it available for all your documents.

Comment: Thank you for at least getting me one step further.  The copy of tikz-network.sty in the local directory did, in fact, work.  However, I went to /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ and found that the following integration failed:
    $ mkdir tikz-network; cd tikz-network; wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-network/tikz-network.sty

Comment: @jlettvin What exactly failed? Downloading the file? Or using the style in your documents? Did you run `sudo mktexlsr` afterwards? See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/ at _Method 3 Install manually_.

Comment: Thank you.  sudo mktexlsr did the trick.  So, now, I assume that for simple 1 file *.sty files I need I can mkdir, wget,mktexlsr, and that is all that's needed.  Right?  I still would like to update my texlive installation, but failing and I would like to be able to use tlmgr as in my original question.  Any advice there?