# Replacing a package folder by the latest one

Tags: polyglossia, debian

I just installed latest (2019) vanilla-tex on my linux system. I want to use package `polyglossia` in its latest version. Long ago I [asked](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/370#issuecomment-567811185) the package developer that can I replace the entire folder of polyglossia and get the correct `sty` file at work & he said yes. Now when I did it, XeLaTeX cannot find polyglossia. Also note that I ran `texhash` after that folder replacement. Now how to solve this problem? I want [this](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia) version of polyglossia to work.

My TeX specifications -

```
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1/dev
```

---

Solution suggested by user @moewe worked well, but only for one session. It stopped working when I opened a new session. Why this must be happening? I used all `sudo` privileges while issuing the commands.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich polyglossia.sty` return if you run it on the command line?

Comment: Needless to say that **in general it is a bad idea to manually overwrite files or folders in the tree controlled by your TeX distribution**. (I can see the appeal for short term fixes or last-minute updates and have done things like this myself on occasions, but it always comes with risks.)

Comment: `kpsewhich polyglossia.sty` returned nothing.

Comment: Hrm. Do you have several TeX systems installed on your machine? You mention having a vanilla TeX live. but the `TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian` makes me think you also have a Debian (testing/dev) TeX live? Maybe you replaced the wrong folder? Do you have your system installed as root? Did you run `texhash` as root?

Comment: I can understand. I also hate such shortcuts, but regarding this particular package I've tried everything. Changing the content of the `ldf` file returns errors. Changing the sty file returns errors. Nothing is working, but I need some latest features. :(

Comment: I ran texhash as root, I don't have any other tex installation, but I did not understand your second question (or statement). How to check it?

Comment: How did you install TeX live? Did you install it from TUG.org following the instructions in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864 or did you install it via some `apt`/`apt-get`? Some background for `texhash` can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864 (well worth a read).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106280/discussion-between-niranjan-and-moewe).