# systeme space error

Tags: systeme

I am trying to reduce spaces with in my system of equation with `systeme` package.
[image]
I followed the instruction in the documentation, but it gives me errors.

```
Undefined control sequence. \syssignspace
```

Here is the code I am using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    
\syssignspace{3pt}\syseqspace{10pt}
\systeme{
    x_1 +x_2 -x_3 -2 x_4 -3 x_5= 0{,},
    -3 x_2 +4 x_3 +16 x_4 +25 x_5=0}
\systeme{
    x_1 = -x_2 +x_3 +2 x_4 +3 x_5{,},
    x_2 = +4 x_3 +16 x_4 +25 x_5
}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like the version of `systeme` that you have installed is older than the documentation that you are reading (the command `\syssignspace` was added in version 0.33, dated April 13 2020). So an update of your packages should solve the problem.

Comment: @Marijn I have TeX Live installed, so all the packages are installed automatically. How would I update one?

Comment: That depends on how exactly you installed TeX Live. If you downloaded it from their own website (https://www.tug.org/texlive/) then you also have `tlmgr`, the TeX Live package manager, and you can use that to update packages. Also make sure you have the latest version of TeX Live itself, they release a new version every year and you have to download and install this version yourself (which is not possible with the package manager). If you have TeX Live from a Linux distribution package (installed with `apt` on Ubuntu/Debian, `yum` on Fedora etc) then you need to install updates [...]

Comment: to the packages manually by downloading them from CTAN, compiling and copying to your TeX Live system directory, because the distribution packages are always some time behind the latest version (for example Ubuntu packages are between a few months and 2 years behind).

Comment: @Marijn I have TeX Live 2019 right now. Does it mean that I have to uninstall the current version and install 2020? It took me about 2 hours to install 2019. Is there any way to update the TeX Live itself without reinstalling?

Comment: No, TeX Live 2019 should be ok. The `systeme` package uses the new `\expanded` primitive that was introduced in TeX Live 2019, so 2018 or older would not work but you don't need 2020 for this. Yo do need to update the packages (`systeme` and the dependencies `xstring` and maybe `expl3`) with `tlmgr`.

Comment: @Marijn I tried to run this command from the console `tlmgr update --all`, but it gives me such a message: `tlmgr.pl: Local TeX Live (2019) is older than remote repository (2020).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.`

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that `tlmgr` is also linked to the specific version of TeX Live. You can set the repository to the 2019 version, but then you would not be able to upgrade to the 2020 version of `systeme` that you need. In this case you can try just downloading the style files yourself (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/systeme/systeme.sty http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/systeme/systeme.tex http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring.sty http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring.tex) and put them in the same folder as your document.

Comment: @Marijn Is it possible to put them somewhere so that all my `.tex` documents will see these files?

Comment: Yes, you can check where the files are currently located (`kpsewhich systeme.sty` and `kpsewhich xstring.sty`) and copy the new files there. Probably the path is something like `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/systeme/` (and `/xstring/`).

Comment: Well, I tried it out. Putting `systeme` files(`.sty`, `.tex`) into the folder with my document allows me to use new commands. However, when I ran `kpsewhich systeme.sty` I got the same path you wrote, but there was no `generic` folder, so I created a new one with `system` folder inside and put files into there and, unfortunately, my documents don't see those files.

Comment: Maybe you didn't see the folder as a normal user? this folder is owned by root, so you need to use `sudo` to copy files there. Anyway, if `kpsewhich` says it is in this folder then this folder exists and the old file should be it in, otherwise there is something wrong. You can check with `find . -name "systeme.sty"` from somewhere high up (for example from `/usr`) to check what the filesystem itself reports as the location of this file.

Comment: Ohhh. I looked up closely and it occurs that I miss a folder in the path. I was looking for `generic` folder in `texlive/texmf-dist` but it is located at `texlive/texmf-dist/tex`.
Now everything works perfectly. Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate that!
Maybe consider leaving the answer for those who will look for the similar problem?

Comment: I will vote to close as a duplicate of the general question on package installing, all the comments I made here can also be found in that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system)