# Unable to use chemfig with pdflatex

Tags: chemfig, texlive-2019

I wanted to use the `chemfig` package and installed it using [tllocalmgr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#tllocalmgr) in arch Linux. However when I tried to use `pdflatex` on a tex file [like this one](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/new/template?zipUrl=/project/538a8a7157b86a573d949d4c/download/zip&templateName=ChemestryFormulae&compiler=pdflatex),

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{textwidth=8cm}

\title{Chemestry Formulae}
\author{Team Learn }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

%Simplest working example example
%----------------------------------------------------------
Writting chemical formulae with chemfig is straightforward.

\chemfig{O=H}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{1cm}

%Angles between bonds
%----------------------------------------------------------
To define chemical formulae you can use units that define the angles

\chemfig{A-[1]B-[7]C}

Absolute angles

\chemfig{A-[:50]B-[:-25]C}

Relative angles

\chemfig{A-[::50]B-[::-25]C}
%----------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1cm}

%Rings
%----------------------------------------------------------
Regular polygons

\chemfig{A*5(-B=C-D-E=)}

Incomplete rings are also possible

\chemfig{A*5(-B=C-D)}
%----------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage

%Branched molecule
%----------------------------------------------------------
Branched molecule \vspace{.5cm}

\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
%----------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{1cm}
%Branched ring
%----------------------------------------------------------
Branched ring
\vspace{.5cm}

\chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}

%----------------------------------------------------------

\vspace{2cm}

%Personalized parameters
%----------------------------------------------------------
{\huge 
    \setchemfig{atom sep=2em,bond style={line width=1pt,red,dash pattern=on 2pt off 2pt}}  
    \chemname
    {\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}}
    {Ethanal}
}
%----------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

it gave the following error :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.362 \defKV
        [chemfig]{%
?
```

and the pdf output was weird :

[image: pdf output]

I am new to latex and I mostly use it in Org-mode (emacs) and I noticed that it's pdf output was not correct when I used chemfig so I decided to run `pdflatex` myself and saw these errors. I have `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux)`

Edit: here is pdflatex's [log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkF-Sex1qr3UxiV-TMtnQWz4fVR1wIRI/view?usp=sharing)

log :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.6.16)  17 JUN 2020 18:37
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**img.tex
(./img.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2019/10/15 3.35 The Babel package

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def
File: switch.def 2019/10/15 3.35 Babel switching mechanism
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2019/10/15 3.35 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count88
\U@D=\dimen103

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count89
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
))
(/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen104
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen105

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box27

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
Package: pgf 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2019/10/08 v1.3c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen106
\Gin@req@width=\dimen107
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
\pgf@x=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@xa=\dimen110
\pgf@ya=\dimen111
\pgf@xb=\dimen112
\pgf@yb=\dimen113
\pgf@xc=\dimen114
\pgf@yc=\dimen115
\pgf@xd=\dimen116
\pgf@yd=\dimen117
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count90
\c@pgf@countb=\count91
\c@pgf@countc=\count92
\c@pgf@countd=\count93
\t@pgf@toka=\toks21
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks23
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count94

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count95
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count96
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen118
\pgfmath@count=\count97
\pgfmath@box=\box28
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count98
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen119
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen120
\pgf@picminy=\dimen121
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen122
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen123
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen124
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen125
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen126
\pgf@xx=\dimen127
\pgf@xy=\dimen128
\pgf@yx=\dimen129
\pgf@yy=\dimen130
\pgf@zx=\dimen131
\pgf@zy=\dimen132
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen133
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen134
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen135
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen136
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfpic=\box29
\pgf@hbox=\box30
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box31
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count99
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen137
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen138
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen139
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen140
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen141
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@max=\dimen142
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count100
\pgf@shadingcount=\count101
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box32
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box33
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen143
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen144
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen145
\pgffor@skip=\dimen146
\pgffor@stack=\toks27
\pgffor@toks=\toks28
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count102
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen147
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen148
\tikz@lasty=\dimen149
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen150
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen151
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen152
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen153
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen154
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen155
\tikz@figbox=\box34
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box35
\tikz@tempbox=\box36
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box37
\tikztreelevel=\count103
\tikznumberofchildren=\count104
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count105
\tikz@fig@count=\count106
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count107
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count108
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count109
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count110

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
))) (/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/generic/chemfig/chemfig.tex
Package: chemfig 2020/05/21  v1.54  Draw molecule with an easy syntax (CT)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/simplekv/simplekv.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex 2019/08/03 v3.1.4b (3.1.4b)
\pgfarrowinset=\dimen156
\pgfarrowlength=\dimen157
\pgfarrowwidth=\dimen158
\pgfarrowlinewidth=\dimen159
)
\CF_cntatomgroup=\count111
\CF_cntgroup=\count112
\CF_cntatom=\count113
\CF_cntcycle=\count114
\CF_cntcompound=\count115
\CF_dim=\dimen160
\CF_arrowsize=\dimen161
\CF_zero=\dimen162
\CF_boxlewis=\box38
\CF_box=\box39
\CF_boxstuff=\box40
\CF_testbox=\box41
\CF_chargebox=\box42
\CF_substtoks=\toks29

! Undefined control sequence.
l.362 \defKV
            [chemfig]{%
? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.362 \defKV[
             chemfig]{%
? 
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \CF_atomstyle.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.363 ... \def\CF_atomstyle                    {#1
                                                  },
? 
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \edef \CF_startoffset {\CF_bondoffset 
                                                 }
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \edef \CF_endoffset {\CF_bondoffset 
                                               }
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \CF_currentbondstyle 
                                
l.59 \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(=[1]O)-[7]H}
                                              ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\CF_chemfigb ...anded \expandafter {\CF_atomstyle 
                                                  }},baseline,\unexpanded \e...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\CF_chemfigb ...ed \expandafter {\CF_chemfigstyle 
                                                  }]}\begingroup \let \CF_ho...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\CF_drawatomgroup ... ,at=(CF_node),\CF_nodestyle 
                                                  }\loop \unless \ifnum \CF_...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\iterate ... =1 west\else east\fi ),\CF_nodestyle 
                                                  }\relax \expandafter \iter...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...gle :\CF_currentlength *\CF_atomsep 
                                                  
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\CF_drawatomgroup ... ,at=(CF_node),\CF_nodestyle 
                                                  }\loop \unless \ifnum \CF_...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\iterate ... =1 west\else east\fi ),\CF_nodestyle 
                                                  }\relax \expandafter \iter...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \edef \CF_startoffset {\CF_bondoffset 
                                                 }
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \edef \CF_endoffset {\CF_bondoffset 
                                               }
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \CF_currentbondstyle 
                                
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...gle :\CF_currentlength *\CF_atomsep 
                                                  
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
\CF_drawatomgroup ... ,at=(CF_node),\CF_nodestyle 
                                                  }\loop \unless \ifnum \CF_...
l.68 \chemfig{A*6(-B=C(-CH_3)-D-E-F(=G)=)}
                                          ^^M
? x
 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14204 strings out of 492167
 279459 string characters out of 6131558
 356758 words of memory out of 5000000
 18327 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4245 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 68i,8n,85p,403b,743s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on img.pdf (1 page, 29664 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

So please tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: It is preferable *not* to use the distro package manager to install LaTeX

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin tlmgr is broken in arch linux and even [fix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live#tlmgr) doesnt work. I tried installing manually as [described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) but even that didn't work. here is pdflatex's [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkF-Sex1qr3UxiV-TMtnQWz4fVR1wIRI/view?usp=sharing) (updated in the answer as well)

Comment: Or use upstream TL (tug.org/texlive) instead of what ever it is arch is providing. Also we generally do not like going to external sites for code or logs as external links rot over time and thus your question will not be usable for others.

Comment: @daleif I have updated the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: No issues using Upstream TL2020 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Additionally also compiles using my frozen (no more updates) upstream TL2019.

Comment: `\defKV` is defined by the `simplekv` package. Your log shows that it is loaded so my guess is that your version of said package is outdated...

Comment: @cgnieder This is weird because I just installed all the packages and texlive few days ago. Anyway manually updating `simplekv` fixed the issue. Thank you and Sorry for causing trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the package `simplekv` using `tllocalmgr` and while that fixed the problem with `chemfig`, I was still getting errors with other packages so I uninstalled Arch's `texlive` installation and instead used an [upstream installer](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/texlive-installer/). After doing this everything works perfectly and even `tlmgr` works.

So the answer would be to not use distro's package manager.

Comment: Indeed it is the way ;-)