# File 'IEEEtrantools.sty' not found. \usepackage

Tags: ieeetran, texlive-2020

I've texlive2020 installed, I am using ubuntu 20.04 if that matters. I'm getting this error (File 'IEEEtrantools.sty' not found. \usepackage) while compiling my tex file. I've found a workaround by placing IEEEtrantools.sty in every directory where there is a .tex file. Which is not an ideal thing to do. In windows 10 I don't have this issue. So, I checked the texlive installation for windows to make sure if the linux one isn't missing something. In this case it's not. I want to know if there exist a better solution. Also, is this problem unique to ieeetrantools? Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: How did you install TeX live 2020? I'm assuming it is a vanilla install from TUG.org (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864)? Have you tried `tlmgr install IEEEtran` (possibly with `sudo` depending on your install location)? What do `kpsewhich IEEEtrantools.sty` and `ieeetrantools.sty` report when you execute them from the command line?

Comment: According to https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/IEEEtran/, `IEEEtrantools.sty` should be present in `IEEEtran`. I'm wondering if this could be a case sensitivity issue if the file is present but not found.

Comment: @moewe I've done an offline installation for the .iso file. When executed from commandline `kpsewhich IEEEtrantools.sty`  and `ieeetrantools.sty` return nothing. The file IEEEtrantools.sty exist in the IEEEtran directory, as I've mentioned it works properly in windows 10 and when I checked the installation in ubuntu with that of windows 10 all the files were present. So, I don't know whether it's an issue with that particular package as I have not encountered any problems with other packages. Also, this was the only reason why I still have windows 10 on my machine.

Comment: Did you run `mktexlsr` or similar after you installed the package? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system for some pointers.