# tocbibind.sty on CentOS 8

Tags: tocbibind, centos

A latex build lacks `tocbibind.sty` on my CentOS 8 box. Doing

```
$ sudo dnf install 'tex(tocbibind.sty)'
```

did not find it. Neither

```
$ sudo dnf whatprovides tocbibind.sty
```

has found it. I did a

```
$ sudo dnf install texlive-*
```

before. Also a

```
$ sudo dnf update
```

How can I install the sought `tocbibind.sty` onto my CentOS?

Comment: neither $ find / -name tocbibind.sty   finds it

Comment: You can always install it manually, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/ under **Method 3**.