# Error when trying to install packages with tlmgr in Linux

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, tlmgr, maintenance

Hello to you all and thanks for reading!

For a while I've been using LaTeX to type university math reports and such using TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian, installed using `apt`) in my laptop with ubuntu xenial (I'm using a basic install). It's not a laptop with a lot of space, so I install the packages manually when I need them (and so far, when it comes to copying .sty files, I do it well). However, when I need to install somewhat more complicated packages (such as `ec`) I get crazy and eventually give up.

Why? I can't get `tlmgr` working for some reason. I'm not that expert in this subject, but for reading similar questions I think this is a path related issue (whatever that is). Right now, when I write `tlmgr install ec` I get this:

```
tlmgr: Cannot load TeX Live database from https://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

The idea is to properly set up `tlmgr` to use it to maintain my install without nasty manual package installation. If you need further details I'll be happy to provide them either in comments or editing this question. Thank you all!

EDIT: So based on a comment I checked out [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system) and I first wrote `which tlmgr`. The output was `/usr/bin/tlmgr`. Then I wrote `sudo /usr/bin/tlmgr install ec` and this happened:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Cannot load TeX Live database from https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install texlive from the debian repositoiries? In this case I *strongly recommend* to get the packages from there as well. Using `tlmgr` in parallel with `apt` tends to lead to issues.

Comment: @Christian so then can you install packages using `apt` directly? And they are recognized directly by texlive? Okay I need to know more

Comment: Almost all packages I am using are available in the repositories. If you want to install all of them, you can try `texlife-full` and most packages are available in one of the `texlive-[something]` packages.

Comment: On Debian `tlmgr` is changed such that it can no longer install packages as Debian want you to install the latex packages via apt instead. This is super confusing since the Debian latex packages are bundles og latex packages. I'd recommend installing hhf `apt-file`  tool, once installed and after you run `sudo apt-file update` then `apt-file search package.sty` will tell you which Debian pa kage provides thst package.

Comment: Okay this works perfect! Thank you @daleif