# How to get the full path of TeXLive tree root?

Tags: texlive, paths

I know that it's `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist` on my machine (MacOS), but how can I get this path programmatically from the command line? I don't see it in my `env`, but `tlmgr` works perfectly: installs and removes packages at this location.

Comment: `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST` or `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFMAIN` should point to that directory (see e.g. https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3). In general `kpsewhich` is used to find files for TeX.

Comment: @moewe this works. Please, turn this into an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the subtree in which system-installed packages are located by typing

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST
```

in the command line. See https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-110002.3 for other `texmf` trees and their meaning.

In general, TeX uses `kpsewhich` to find system-installed files. If you are looking for a specific file

```
kpsewhich <filename>
```

e.g. `kpsewhich article.cls` is really helpful.

---

Remember not to install any files manually into `TEXMFDIST`. Also do not modify any files there. The subtree is controlled by your TeX distribution (primarily by `tlmgr`): files can be overwritten or deleted at any time. Manual installations can go into `TEXMFLOCAL` (system wide, usually needs admin/root permission) or `TEXMFHOME` (user-specific, usually does not need special permissions). ([Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/35864), [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/35864))