# I installed TeXlive through APT but I need a TeX package that I can't install individually; how do I install specific TeX packages outside APT? tlmgr?

Tags: installing, tlmgr, installing-fonts

I'm on Linux Mint 21, Ubuntu based. I installed TeXlive from apt from official repos.
I need Fira Sans, but `Texlive-fonts-extra` is 1.5 gigabytes. I don't want to install all the fonts. How do I install just select packages like just Fira Sans?

I am told I can install the Fira package through

```
tlmgr install fira
```

This did not work. I got

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md) TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/user/texmf tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

I tried searching and it told me to run `tlmgr init-usertree`. It seemed to complete successfully. I ran `tlmgr install fira` again. I got

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022). Cross release updates are only supported with update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

It seems okay? But when I ran TeXstudio it gave me the error

```
File \FiraSans.sty' not found. \RequirePackage`
```

which seems to suggest that Fira wasn't installed correctly. Running as root got me nowhere.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I install `FiraSans.sty` without using APT to download `Texlive-fonts-extra`?

Comment: We have quite a few questions about installing some or all of TeXLive in Linux: start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/86

Comment: `tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2022).` means it did not install anything

Comment: You cannot install packages using the Debian modified version of `tlmgr`. Debian wants you to install via apt. And Debian TeXLive is not packaged such that you can install individual LaTeX packages. You can only do that if you use upstream TeXLive where `tlmgr` is not modified.

Comment: I think I have my answer, I *can't* install on tlmgr outside apt. Thank you.

Comment: Installing individual packages manually by downloading them from CTAN is usually quite easy, but for font packages it is a bit more involved with several helper programs, cache refresh etc. It is certainly possible but it needs some work and technical knowledge. So in that case you are better off installing the font-extra apt package, or use XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX with a .ttf or .otf version of the font (which does not require any font-specific package to be installed), or use Overleaf. Or uninstall the apt distribution altogether and use the native TeX Live installer.

Answer (score 3):

In general a LaTeX dist installed via `apt` needs to be updated via `apt`.

Even though it often comes with the `tlmgr` tool, the `apt` version of `tlmgr` has been changed such that it cannot install packages. [1]

[1] Given that packages installable from CTAN is only available to a given TeXLive version for about a year, the `apt` TeXLive is often behind, and would be refused anyway.

In addition, the way LaTeX is packaged in the `apt` installation, it is more or less impossible to install an individual package. It all comes in `apt` packages that we might label as *bundles*.

There are two ways to install a particular package in this case.

1. use `apt-file` to look up which `apt` bundle provides `file.sty`. As you mention in this case it is `texlive-fonts-extra`
2. Drop the `apt` based LaTeX installation and manually install upstream TeXLive (see https://tug.org/texlive). This has the benefit of getting access to the full `tlmgr` and here you can start of by installing a small TeXLive and then add individual packages afterwards.

Comment: Thank you. If I install it manually, how do a clean uninstall of the TeXlive installed via apt? `apt purge texlive*`? If I install it manually, will programs like pandoc and TeXstudio be able to use the manually installed TeXlive if TeXlive is decoupled from the apt system?

Comment: Something like that. With the manual install you need to be very careful manually adding the new PATH, you should probably added to both `.bashrc` and `.profile` and then log out and in again (`.profile` is only read at login), Then LaTeX should be found by other programmes.

Comment: If you have the space on your harddrive, så can just leave the APT installation. Just make sure that the new path for the manual TeXLive is added to the **front** of the PATH, then it is found first and overrules the `apt` one.