# tabularray: functional library does not exist on my vanila texlive installation

Tags: texlive, tabularray, functional

When I try to compile the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \test {} {
  \cellSetText{1}{1}{modfied}
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}[process=\test]{
   width=50mm,
   colspec={XX}}
 original & original\\
 original & original\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

with pdflatex test.tex
I get the following:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tabularray/tabularray.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \IgnoreSpacesOn
                   
?
```

It seems that the functional package is not part of my (vanila) TeX live installation. Is this a known issue or is there something wrong with my installation or my code ?

Thank you for your help,

Jouke

Comment: Try adding explicit `\usepackage{functional}`

Comment: I tried that but: ! LaTeX Error: File `functional.sty' not found. It seems that the functional package is missing :-(

Comment: Yes then find some way to install it, the package is rather new so probably not in TeX live yet.  (the exact method depends on your operating system, I think.)

Comment: [installing - How do I install an individual package on a Linux system? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/73017#73017)

Comment: The functional library was added this spring, see https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/commit/81ca081737ff14983f365b5565c5e88c6ab7f1b9 If you want an up-to-date texlive, ditch the texlive packaged for debian and install a vanilla texlive

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks.