# I cannot make the package lwarp works

Tags: packages, lwarp

When I load the package lwarp with the command `\usepackage{lwarp}` and I press F1 (or compile/build) I get the error with the file

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp.sty

at the line 33. Within that file, above line 33 is the command: `\RequirePackage{ifptex}`
So I thought the problem should be that missing package, and indeed the error message says:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `ifptex.sty' not found.Type X to quit or  to proceed,or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)Enter file name:! Emergency stop. flag __ ^^M

So I searched for that package and found it here [ifptex.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/ifptex). Now I created a directory for that package: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifptex/ and put there the package, but that doesn't fix the problem (I get the same message). I tried to put the ifptex package near the location of the other required packages (iftex and ifpdf) i.e.

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex

I created a folder at generic/ifptex but didn't work, I put the ifptex.sty file in the folder iftex but also didn't work.

My question is, why is this not working? How can I install the package properly?
The instruction in the readme file says for installation:

> In a system compliant to TDS 1.1, move the files as follows:
> *.sty → $TEXMF/tex/generic/ifptex

Which I have done so far, but I get the same error message.

I'm using TeXMaker 5.0.3 (compiled with Qt 5.15.3) with TeXlive in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Try [running `mktexlsr`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73017/270600) maybe?

Comment: the files under usr share are  managed by apt you should not add files there by hand just install texlive-full or a suitable subset via apt

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have texlive-full.

Comment: @JoséMarín then if your texlive is new enough to have lwarp at all then `lwarp.sty` should be at `texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp.sty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is and is not working.

Comment: and ifptex should already be at `texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifptex/ifptex.sty`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it's there, together with ifuptex.sty.

Comment: I installed texlive-full following this: https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html (and not by apt or synaptic).

Comment: @JoséMarín but that is an upstream texlive, probably installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2022` and completely unrelated to the apt-managed system texlive in your question installed under `/usr/share/texlive`

Comment: Yes, I have that directory. So my TeXmaker is not using my TeXlive-full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the answer given here: [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system/73017#73017) by @Loop Space using *method 1*. A brief summary here:

I typed in the terminal:

```
which tlmgr
```

to know where is tlmgr:

> /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr

then I run the command:

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr install ifptex
```

and that solves my problem.  Thank you.

### Edit and comments clarification

This edit is because at first I made an error, I wrote a wrong solution, I spot the error thanks to @David Carlisle. I got confused, but now I think this is really the answer that solved my problem.

### "Update"

Well I don't know if this is an update, but there is another way to install individual packages using the (Synaptic) Package Manager.
First thing you need to know is the name of the package where the package is, I will explain below.
For example if I got an error with `\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}` then I have to install the [ieeetran](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) LaTeX package, but in what debian package is that LaTeX package?
To know that use the following command:

```
apt-cache search ieeetran
```

Or in general:

```
apt-cache search <name of the package>
```

That will print the name you are looking for. In this hypothetical case: texlive-publishers. Next just install it via (Synaptic) Package Manager

Comment: no sorry this answer is completely misleading.  `sudo apt-get install` will have installed files in the system tex under /usr/share it will have done nothing to the texlive installed under /usr/local which is managed by `tlmgr` not `apt`

Comment: This solves my problem, now lwarp package is working fine (because ifptex was installed this way).

Comment: Glad you have got it working but you are using the debian system tex, not the one you installed from tug, That is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I see your point. I edited the answer to fix that.