# Unable to use physics2 package (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS)

Tags: packages, compiling, tlmgr, physics

I installed LaTeX/texlive yesterday (say, day X) using `apt`. The exact command I've use was:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

but now (day X+1) I'm having troubles when I try to use the [physics2 package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2) in my document. For example, the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%\usepackage{physics2}
\begin{document}

asdasd

\end{document}
```

works perfect but when I uncomment `\usepackage{physics2}`, it doesn't work. I belive that I don't have the package `physics2` installed because I got this error:

```
File 'physics2.sty' not found
```

I'm using `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`. When I try to use `sudo tlmgr install physics2` (or to update) I get:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /home/peluche/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

(I already read the documentation but I don't fully understand what I have to do or to initialize). Any idea how to make `physics2` package work? (I'm still a noob at Ubuntu and LaTeX's errors/packages by the way)

Comment: Did you install texlive via `apt` or the independent installer (https://tug.org/texlive/)?

Comment: By using `apt`, yes. The exact command I used was `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`. I installed LaTeX (texlive) yesterday

Comment: update your texlive usig apt, you an use texlive-full  or seach which apt package it is in

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believe I have the lastest version of texlive: `TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)`. Should I [look here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) the package?

Comment: [`physics2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2) has only been on CTAN for a few days, while I am seeing it as available through `tlmgr` on a [vanilla](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/106162) install, it might take a while before it's added to the Ubuntu packages.

Comment: oooh, I didn't know that. Now it makes more sense why it didn't get installed

Comment: You installed TeXlive as root, yet you seem to update TeXlive as user. That will result in a conflict between directories as the root install makes the distribution systemside available . What does the command `sudo tlmgr install physics2` result into?

Comment: Using `sudo tlmgr install physics2` gets the same result/error/warning

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've installed TeX Live via `apt`, you have the Ubuntu-packaged version of TeX Live and should be updating it by updating `texlive-full` via `apt`, rather than trying to use `tlmgr`.

With `texlive-full` you should have all pacakges, but [`physics2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2) has only been on CTAN for a few days  and so it will take some time before the Ubuntu-package TeX Live is rebuilt to include it.

In the meantime [`physics2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2) does appear to be available via `tlmgr` on a [vanilla install](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/106162), so you could remove the `apt`-installed `texlive-full` and instead use the TeX Live installer at https://tug.org/texlive/, or attempt to manually install [`physics2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/physics2) independently of `apt`/`tlmgr` following [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/106162).